# Prime factorization of Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, gaussian-integers

> I want to find $a, b\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $a(2+3i)+b(5+5i)=1$.

I don't know how to do this, but my first thought was to do something with the norm or otherwise factoring $5+5i=(2+i)(2-i)(1+i)$, but I don't see how to use this further.

The second question is for which $x\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ we have $x=1\bmod (2-+3i)$ and $x=-1\bmod(5+5i)$? But I would like to try and solve this myself as soon as I have the first question.

Edit: I will attempt to solve this using the Euclidean algorithm as stated in the comments. I will be back later with more! (Although I would not mind if someone beat me to it) ;)

Comment: Use the Euclidean algorithm, with the norm as the size function for the remainder.

Comment: @rogerl Is there maybe another way without usung the Euclidian algorithm?

Comment: @TR-8R I'm pretty sure there is no easier and faster way than Euclidean algorithm. Another way of doing that is trial and error.

Comment: @Wojowu Okay thanks

Comment: @rogerl Thank you too :)

Comment: Why do you want another method?

Comment: You have $(2a+5b)+(3a+5b)i=1$ which give you the solution solving the linear system $2a+5b=1$ and $3a+5b=0$.

Comment: @Piquito But the coefficients have to be in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, your method gives me $b=3/5$

Comment: As Piquito noted, the value of $a, b$ are not purely integers.

Comment: @rogerl I'm not such a huge fan of it, but I'll give it a go later and tell you how it went!

Comment: For example, you could write $a = r+si$ and $b = t+ui$, expand, and solve the linear system, then stare at it to find integer solutions.

Comment: A machinery approach shows there are lots of such that $a$ and $b$: $$[ -6, -1 ][ 3, 1 ],~
[ -6, 9 ][ 4, -4 ],~
[ -1, -6 ][ 0, 3 ],~
$$

Comment: @TR-8R: I see now the true question. Thank you. Tomorrow I' ll post  an answer I have deduced,......but not in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021), modified for Gaussian integers, we get
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&2&-1+2i&1-i\\\hline
1&0&1&1-2i&2+3i\\
0&1&-2&-1+4i&-5-5i\\
5+5i&2+3i&1-i&1&0
\end{array}\tag{1}
$$
This says that
$$
(1-2i+(2+3i)k)\color{#C00000}{(5+5i)}+(-1+4i-(5+5i)k)\color{#C00000}{(2+3i)}=1\tag{2}
$$
where $k$ is a Gaussian integer. For example, $k=i$ gives the solution
$$
\underbrace{(-2)\color{#C00000}{(5+5i)}}_{-10-10i}+\underbrace{(4-i)\color{#C00000}{(2+3i)}}_{11+10i}=1\tag{3}
$$

---

Since $-10-10i=(-2)(5+5i)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
-10-10i&\equiv1\pmod{2+3i}\\
-10-10i&\equiv0\pmod{5+5i}
\end{align}\tag{4}
$$
and since $11+10i=(4-i)(2+3i)$
$$
\begin{align}
11+10i&\equiv0\pmod{2+3i}\\
11+10i&\equiv1\pmod{5+5i}
\end{align}\tag{5}
$$
Adding $a$ times $(4)$ and $b$ times $(5)$ gives a solution to
$$
\begin{align}
x&\equiv a\pmod{2+3i}\\
x&\equiv b\pmod{5+5i}
\end{align}\tag{6}
$$

---

Applying $(6)$ to the particular question above
$$
\begin{align}
-21-20i&\equiv \phantom{-}1\pmod{2+3i}\\
-21-20i&\equiv -1\pmod{5+5i}
\end{align}\tag{7}
$$
Since the solution in $(7)$ is given mod $(2+3i)(5+5i)=-5+25i$, adding $(1-i)(-5+25i)=20+30i$, we also get the solution
$$
\begin{align}
-1+10i&\equiv \phantom{-}1\pmod{2+3i}\\
-1+10i&\equiv -1\pmod{5+5i}
\end{align}\tag{8}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Put $a=x+yi$ and $b=u+vi$; operating one has
$(x+yi)(2+3i)+5(u+vi)(1+i)=1$ which gives
 $$\begin{cases}2x-3y+5u-5v=1\\3x+2y+5u+5v=0\end{cases}$$
This is a linear system of two equations with four unknowns so it should normally be infinitely many solutions. It follows, solving respect of $u,v$ $$u=\frac{1+y-5x}{10}\\v=\frac{-x-5y-1}{10}$$ Making now $1+y=10m;\space 5x=10A;\space x-4=10B$ one has $x=10n+4$ and we get a parameterization giving an infinite set of solutions in $\mathbb Z[i]$
$$\begin{cases}x=10n+4\\y=10m-1\\u=m-2-5n\\v=-(5m+n)\end{cases}$$
$\color{red}($*It is easy to verify the identity*

$[10n+4+(10m-1)i](2+3i)+[m-2-5n-(5m+n)i](5+5i)=1\color{red})$