# Find the cubic polynomial given linear reminders after division by quadratic polynomials?

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots, factoring

> A cubic polynomial gives remainders $(13x-2)$ and $(-1-7x)$ when divide by
>   $x^2-x-3$ and $x^2-2x+5$ respectively. Find the polynomial.

I have written this as:

$P(x)=(x^2-x-3)Q(x)+(13x-2)$

$P(x)=(x^2-2x+5)G(x)+(-1-7x)$

and

$P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

The first method I thought about is factoring $(x^2-x-3)$ and $(x^2-2x+5)$ so that I could find roots and thereby $P(root)$ would equal the reminder for the given value of root. As the two quadratic equations would give four roots i.e. four values I can substitute, I would be able to calculate all the four constant $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. However, the first polynomial has very ugly roots and the second one has no real roots so I guess I should find another way. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 4):

Using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021), we get
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&x+6&(x-8)/53\\\hline
1&0&1&-x-6&(x^2-2x+5)/53\\
0&1&-1&x+7&(-x^2+x+3)/53\\
x^2-x-3&x^2-2x+5&x-8&53&0\\
\end{array}
$$
That is,
$$
(x+7)(x^2-2x+5)-(x+6)(x^2-x-3)=53\tag{1}
$$
We can now use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). $(1)$ tells us that
$$
\frac{x+7}{53}\,(x^2-2x+5)\equiv
\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\pmod{x^2-2x+5}\\
1&\pmod{x^2-x-3}
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}
$$
$$
-\frac{x+6}{53}\,(x^2-x-3)\equiv
\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\pmod{x^2-2x+5}\\
0&\pmod{x^2-x-3}
\end{array}\right.\tag{3}
$$
Add $13x-2$ times $(2)$ and $-1-7x$ times $(3)$ to get
$$
\frac1{53}\left(20x^4+99x^3-185x^2+338x-88\right)\tag{4}
$$
taking the remainder of $(4)$ mod $(x^2-x-3)(x^2-2x+5)$ gives
$$
3x^3-5x^2+6x+4\tag{5}
$$

Comment: good. I had gotten as far as the $x+7$ and $x+6$ and the $53.$ I think this ought to be part of the lesson, that this is CRT.

Comment: @WillJagy: I have added a mention that $(2)$ and $(3)$, which follow from $(1)$, can be used with the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: very nice. I had not even noticed that crt gives a quartic, and a final reduction is needed to get down to cubic. Also, Barcelona 4, Deportivo 0, 54th minute

Answer (score 2):

Since your $P(x)$ is cubic, $Q(x)$ and $G(x)$ are linear.  So 
$$(x^2 - x - 3) (q_1 x + q_0) + (13 x - 2) = (x^2 - 2 x + 5)(g_1 x + g_0) + (-1 - 7 x)$$
Expanding and equating coefficients of like powers, you get four equations in the four unknowns $q_0, q_1, g_0, g_1$.

Alternatively, find the remainder (in terms of $q_1$ and $q_0$) on dividing $(x^2-x-3)(q_1 x + q_0) + 13x-2$ by $x^2-2x+5$, set this equal to $-1-7x$, and solve two equations for $q_0$ and $q_1$.

Comment: +1 though irritated that you just scooped me!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have made an appropriate system of equations and solved it but my results differ from those from the answers in my textbook. I got $3x^3-2x^2+3x+1$ (confirmed by WolframAlpha: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x^2-x-3%29%28ax%2Bb%29%2B13x-2%3D%28x^2-2x%2B5%29%28cx%2Bd%29-1-7x&x=0&y=0 ) but according to the textbook the answer is $3x^3-5x^2+6x+4$ could you please verify if I have done this correctly?

Comment: It's easy enough to check.   The remainders on dividing $3x^3 - 2x^2 + 3 x + 1$ by $x^2-x-3$ and $x^2 -2x+5$ are $13x+4$ and $-4x-19$ respectively.  So you must have done something wrong.  The textbook's answers are correct.