# Can $a \equiv x \cdot b$ (mod $m$) be solved for $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose I have $a \equiv x \cdot b$ (mod $m$) and I know the value of $a, b, m$. 
The value of $m$ is of the form $2^n$ (I don't know if that even helps)...

I want to know if there exist a unique value of $x$ in $[0, m -1)$ that satisfies the equation. And if so, then how do I obtain it?

This is what I've done so far:

First I considered $a$ and $b$ to be between $0$ and $m-1$

$a \equiv x \cdot b$ (mod $m$) 
$$m | (bx - a)$$
$$bx - a = km$$
$$x = \frac{km + a}{b}$$
Since $x$ ranges from $0$ to $m-1$, $k$ must be from $0$ to $b-1$

I'm confused how to proceed from here...

Comment: Do you know the extended Euclidean algorithm and the Bézout indetity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation has a unique solution if and only if $b$ is a unit modulo $m$, which happens if and only if $b$ and $m$ are coprime.

There is a fast algorithm to find the solution: [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

To solve
$$
a\equiv xb\pmod{m}\tag{1}
$$
we can solve
$$
xb+ym=a\tag{2}
$$
which requires $\gcd(b,m)\mid a$. Thus, we would like to solve
$$
x\frac{b}{\gcd(b,m)}+y\frac{m}{\gcd(b,m)}=\frac{a}{\gcd(b,m)}\tag{3}
$$
To solve $(3)$, we can use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). One implementation is detailed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021).