# Find $(x + 1)^{−3}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^4 + 1)$

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

In a previous question, I established that $x^5 + x^4 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^4 + 1)$, so it will not be divisible by $x+1$. Hence $x^5+x^4+1$ will be coprime to $(x+1)^3 = x^3+x^2+x+1$

So far I have used the Euclidean algorithm to get:

$x^5+x^4+1 = (x^3+x^2+x+1)(x^2+1) + x$

$x^3+x^2+x+1 = (x^2+1)(x+1) + 0$

However, I know I have done something wrong - because the Euclidean algorithm should show that the gcd of $x^5+x^4+1$ and $x^3+x^2+x+1$ is $1$, not $(x^2+1)$.

Comment: $x^5+x^4+1$ is not irreducible$\bmod 2$.  $(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)$

Comment: The next step is to divide $x^3+x^2+x+1$ by $x$, not $x+1$.

Comment: You are looking for $p$ and $q$ such that $(x+1)^3p = 1 + (x^5+x^4+1)q$. Or what is the same $(x+1)^3p - (x^5+x^4+1)q = 1$. Use Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy Read the question through...

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Andrews, sorry I realise my mistake now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the algorithm detailed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021/13854) with polynomials (and writing top to bottom instead of left to right),we get
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
x^5+x^4+1&0&1&\\
x^3+x^2+x+1&1&0&\\
x&x^2+1&1&x^2+1\\
1&\color{#C00}{x^4+x^3+x}&x^2+x+1&x^2+x+1\\
0&x^5+x^4+1&x^3+x^2+x+1&x
\end{array}
$$
which says that in $\mathbb{Z}_2$,
$$
(x^3+x^2+x+1)^{-1}=x^4+x^3+x\pmod{x^5+x^4+1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach to this one, which does not really depend too much on the standard theorems on polynomial rings--except for the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor)--but does rely on a few simple observations about the polynomial

$p(x) = x^5 + x^4 + 1 = 0 \in \Bbb Z_2[x]/(x^5 + x^4 + 1) \tag{1}$

and a lot of grinding away at synthetic division.  Very brutesy-forcey.  I have adopted the notation

$p(x) = x^5 + x^4 + 1 \tag{2}$

because it allows to save typing and $\LaTeX$ all over the place.  I will also,for similar reasons, use the shorthand

$R = \Bbb Z_2[x]/(p(x)).  \tag{2}$

These things being said:.

We have

$p(x) = x^5 + x^4 + 1 = 0 \in R;  \tag{3}$

this much is, I think, obvious.  Now (3) implies

$x^5 + x^4 = 1 \in R, \tag{4}$

which follows from adding $1$ to each side of (3) and using the fact that $R$ is of characteristic $2$.

Then

$x^4(x + 1) = x^5 +x^4 = 1, \tag{5}$

which proves that $1 + x$ is in fact a unit in $R$ and that its inverse is $x^4$.  We may now take the third power of each side of (5); we find

$x^{12}(1 + x)^3 = 1; \tag{6}$

from this we see that

$(1 + x)^{-3} = x^{12}.  \tag{7}$

In a sense, we are now done.  However, for the sake of good form if nothing else, the effort should be nade to reduce $(1 + x)^{-3}$ to a polynomial of degree less than $5$, since in principle $R$ need contain no powers of $x$ greater than $4$ by virtue of (3) and (4).  We accomplish this reduction by computing the renainder of $x^{12}$ when divided by $p(x)$, *via* synthetic division.  And here is where brute force comes into play.  In what follows I shall recite the steps of the computation, presenting the quotient and remainder at each one, denoting the quotient by $q(x)$ and the remainder by $r(x)$:

1.)  we divide $p(x)$ into $x^{12}$, and find

$q(x) = x^7, r(x) = x^{11} + x^7; \tag{13}$

2.)  $p(x)$ into $r(x)$:

$q(x) = x^6, r(x) = x^{10} + x^7 + x^6; \tag{14}$

3.)  $p(x)$ into $r(x)$:

$q(x) = x^5, r(x) = x^9 + x^7 + x^6 +x^5; \tag{15}$

4.)  $p(x)$ into $r(x)$:

$q(x) = x^4, r(x) = x^8 + x^7 + x^6 +x^5 +x^4\tag{16}$

5.)  $p(x)$ into $r(x)$:

$q(x) = x^3, r(x) = x^6 +x^5 +x^4 +x^3; \tag{17}$

6.)  $p(x)$ into $r(x)$:

$q(x) = x, r(x) = x^4 +x^3 +x; \tag{18}$

since $\deg r(x) < 5$, we may stop at this point, in accord with the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor).  According to these calculations, we then have

$(1 + x)^{-3} = x^4 +x^3 +x. \tag{19}$

We can in fact check (20) as follows:

$(x^4 + x^3 + x)(1 + x)^3 = (x^4 + x^3 + x)(1 + x)^2(1 + x); \tag{20}$

since

$(1 + x)^2 = 1 + x^2 \tag{21}$

in $R$, we have

$(x^4 + x^3 + x)(1 + x)^2 = (x^4 + x^3 + x)(1 + x^2) = x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x; \tag{22}$

at last, we note that *via* (3)

$x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x = x(x^5 + x^4 + 1) + x^4 = x^4, \tag{23}$

and thus

$(x^4 + x^3 + x)(1 + x)^3 = x^4(1 + x) = x^5 + x^4 = 1, \tag{24}$

validating our calculation of

$(1 + x)^{-3} = x^4 + x^3 + x \in R. \tag{25}$

Comment: Fiat lux! In the earliest steps you can also mod out by $p(x)^2=x^{10}+x^8+1$. Don't know if it saves much :-/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  Good to hear from you.  Thanks.  Who are our moderators at present, by the way?  I liked your answer, a sweeter calculation than my grunge!

Comment: Not much difference, I combined a few steps. No changes in the moderator team for the last couple of years - for better or for worse :-)