# Solve the system of linear congruences below by finding all $x$ that satisfy it.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Question: Solve the system of linear congruences below by finding all $x$ that satisfy it. Hint — try rewriting each congruence in the form $x \equiv a \pmod b$.

$2x \equiv 1 \pmod3$

$3x \equiv 2 \pmod5$

$5x \equiv 4 \pmod7$

So I tried following that hint, and I have:

$x \equiv 2 \pmod3$

$x \equiv 4 \pmod5$

$x \equiv 5 \pmod7$

Firstly, is this correct? Second, where do  I go from here? I calculated that $M = 3 \times 5 \times 7 = 105$ and the individual $M_i$'s, but now I'm stuck in a circle, because reducing from there gives me back the original equations. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct. Now, apply the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Computation).

Answer (score 0):

from the first both equations we get
$$\frac{3}{2}(1+3m)=2+5n$$ or $$9m-10n=1$$ solving this Diophantine equation we get
$$m=9+10C$$
$$n=8+9C$$ with this two equations you can calculate $x$

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), one implementation can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021), we can solve the three equations
$$
3x+35y=1=12\cdot3-1\cdot35
$$
$$
5x+21y=1=-4\cdot5+1\cdot21
$$
$$
7x+15y=1=-2\cdot7+1\cdot15
$$
which gives the equations
$$
\begin{align}
-35&\equiv1\pmod3\\
-35&\equiv0\pmod5\\
-35&\equiv0\pmod7
\end{align}\tag1
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
21&\equiv0\pmod3\\
21&\equiv1\pmod5\\
21&\equiv0\pmod7
\end{align}\tag2
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
15&\equiv0\pmod3\\
15&\equiv0\pmod5\\
15&\equiv1\pmod7
\end{align}\tag3
$$
Adding $2$ times $(1)$ to $4$ times $(2)$ and $5$ times $(3)$ should give an answer mod $105$.