# Solving the congruence $9x \equiv 3 \pmod{47}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For this question $9x \equiv 3 \pmod{47}$.

I used euler algorithm and found that the inverse is $21$ as $21b-4a=1$
when $a=47$ and $b=9$

I subbed back into the given equation:
\begin{align*}
(9)(21) & \equiv 3 \pmod{47}\\
189 & \equiv 3 \pmod{47}\\
63 & \equiv 1 \pmod{47}
\end{align*}
and I'm stuck, should I divide $63$ by $9$ to get $7$? but it does not comply to the given equation as when $x=7$, it would become $16 \pmod{47}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @coffee Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

you can write $$x\equiv \frac{3}{9}=\frac{1}{3}\equiv \frac{48}{3}\equiv 16\mod 47$$

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating this. First of all$$9x\equiv3\pmod{47}\iff47\mid3.(3x-1)\iff47\mid3x-1.$$Besides, the inverse of $3$ $\pmod{47}$ is$16$. So$$47\mid3x-1\iff47\mid16.(3x-1)\iff47|x-16.$$So, the solutions are thos integers $x$ such that $x\equiv16\pmod{47}$.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to solve the congruence $9x \equiv 3 \pmod{47}$.  You correctly found that $21$ is the multiplicative inverse of $9$ modulo $47$.  However, you made an error in this step:
$$9 \cdot 21 \equiv \color{red}{3} \pmod{47}$$
If we multiply one side of the congruence by $21$, we must multiply the other side of the congruence by $21$.  You should have obtained 
\begin{align*}
21 \cdot 9x & \equiv 21 \cdot 3 \pmod{47}\\
1x & \equiv 63 \pmod{47}\\
x & \equiv 16 \pmod{47}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

By [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) since $\gcd(9,47)=1$ we know that exist $a,b$ integers such that

$$9a+47b=1$$

then

$$\iff 9a=1-47 b \iff 9a\equiv 1 \pmod{47}$$

The integer "$a$" is defined the multiplicative inverse of $9 \mod 47$ and can be easily found by [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). In this case we found that

- $21\cdot9-4\cdot 47=1\implies a=21$

Once we have the inverse we can find the solution that is

- $9x \equiv 3 \pmod{47}\iff 21\cdot9x \equiv 21\cdot3 \pmod{47}\iff x\equiv 63\equiv 16 \pmod{47}$

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021),
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&5&4&2\\\hline
1&0&1&-4&9\\
0&1&-5&21&-47\\
47&9&2&1&0\\
\end{array}
$$
shows that $21\cdot9-4\cdot47=1$ so we want $63\cdot9-12\cdot47=3$ which can be reduced, by subtracting $47$ from $63$ and $9$ from $12$, to
$$
16\cdot9-3\cdot47=3
$$