# Is $41$ a square mod $10^6$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble with this question, and I was wondering how I would go about solving such problems with high congruences.

I know we cannot use the Legendre symbol to compute this, as $10^6$ is not prime and the Legendre symbol is not multiplicative in its denominator.
How would I go about solving problems such as this?

Comment: $203821^2 = 41543000041 \equiv 41 \pmod{10^6}$

Comment: Hint:use the *Chinese remainder theorem* for $2$ and $5$, then *Hensel's lifting* for $2^6 and $5^6$, then again the C.R.T.

Comment: $41$ is a square $\bmod 10^{anything▪you▪want}$.  It is a square in both $2$-adics and $5$-adics.

Comment: @Bernard *Exactly* 100k as of this comment. Amazing! Congrats! :)

Comment: @Deepak: Thanks! What was the probability this happened, b.t.w.? ;o)

Comment: @Bernard That would make an interesting question - but don't post it, 'cos your rep will change. :)

Comment: Not just $10^6$. $41$ is a square $\bmod 10^n$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Answer (score 1):

[Hensel lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) gives
$$
\begin{align}
1^2&\equiv41\pmod2\\
1^2&\equiv41\pmod4\\
1^2&\equiv41\pmod8\\
5^2&\equiv41\pmod{16}\\
13^2&\equiv41\pmod{32}\\
13^2&\equiv41\pmod{64}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
1^2&\equiv41\pmod5\\
21^2&\equiv41\pmod{25}\\
71^2&\equiv41\pmod{125}\\
71^2&\equiv41\pmod{625}\\
696^2&\equiv41\pmod{3125}\\
696^2&\equiv41\pmod{15625}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, since $(x+32)^2\equiv x^2\pmod{64}$, we get
$$
45^2\equiv41\pmod{64}
$$

---

Using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021)
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&244&7&9\\\hline
1&0&1&-7&64\\
0&1&-244&1709&-15625\\
15625&64&9&1&0\\
\end{array}
$$
says that
$$
1709\cdot64-7\cdot15625=1
$$

---

Thus, since $57\cdot15625=890625$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
890625&\equiv1\pmod{64}\\
890625&\equiv0\pmod{15625}
\end{align}
$$
and since $1709\cdot64=109376$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
109376&\equiv0\pmod{64}\\
109376&\equiv1\pmod{15625}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, since $13\cdot890625+696\cdot109376=87703821$, we have
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{
\begin{align}
703821^2&\equiv41\pmod{1000000}\\
296179^2&\equiv41\pmod{1000000}
\end{align}
}
$$
Furthermore, since $-13\cdot890625+696\cdot109376=64547571$, we have
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{
\begin{align}
547571^2&\equiv41\pmod{1000000}\\
452429^2&\equiv41\pmod{1000000}
\end{align}
}
$$
Therefore, since $45\cdot890625+696\cdot109376=116203821$, we have
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{
\begin{align}
203821^2&\equiv41\pmod{1000000}\\
796179^2&\equiv41\pmod{1000000}
\end{align}
}
$$
Furthermore, since $-45\cdot890625+696\cdot109376=36047571$, we have
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{
\begin{align}
47571^2&\equiv41\pmod{1000000}\\
952429^2&\equiv41\pmod{1000000}
\end{align}
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with complicated algebra.

Think of a number from its decimal structure $X=(x_0x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5)_{(10)}$ there is 6 variables atleast needed to assert the congruence with 1000000.

**Squaring X:**

$x_0\ x_1\ x_2\ x_3\ x_4\ x_5*\\
x_0\ x_1\ x_2\ x_3\ x_4\ x_5=\\
x_0^2 10^0+\\
2x_0x_1 10^1+\\
(2x_0x_2+x_1^2) 10^2+\\
(2x_0x_3+2x_1x_2) 10^3+\\
(2x_0x_4+2x_1x_3+x_2^2) 10^4+\\
(2x_0x_5+2x_1x_4+2x_2x_3) 10^5+...$

More digits follow but this is what matters, to locate this number we just need to assign 1,4,0,0,0,0 to the first edges.

$x_0^2 =1 \rightarrow x_0=1\\
2x_0x_1=4 \rightarrow x_1=2\\
(2x_0x_2+x_1^2)=0 \rightarrow x_2=\{3,8\}\ \text{3 is rejected},c=2\\
(2x_0x_3+2x_1x_2+c)=0 \rightarrow x_3=3, c=4\\
(2x_0x_4+2x_1x_3+x_2^2+c)=0 \rightarrow x_4=0, c=8\\
(2x_0x_5+2x_1x_4+2x_2x_3+c)=0 \rightarrow x_5=5$

We can try now, $(503821)^2=253835600041=41mod10^6$