# $11x + 13 \equiv 4$ (mod 37)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$11x + 13 \equiv 4$ (mod 37)

**My "solution" to the problem**

$11x + 13 \equiv 4$ (mod 37) $\rightarrow$

$11x + 13 = 4 + 37y  $

$11x - 37y = - 9$

**Euclid's algorithm.**

$37 = 11*3 + 4$

$11 = 4*2 + 3$

$4 = 3*1 + 1 \rightarrow GCD(37,11) = 1$

$3 = 1*3 + 0$

**Write as linear equation**

$1 = 4 - 1*3$

$3 = 11 - 2*4$

$4 = 37-3*11$

$1 = 4 -1*3 = 4-1(11-2*4) = 3*4-1*11 = 3(37-3*11)-1*11 = 3*37 -10*11$

$1 = 3*37 -10*11$

$11(10) - 37(3) = -1$

$11(90) - 37(27) = -9$

**x = 90**

That is my answer. But the correct answer should be:

x = 16

Comment: "Euklides algorithm"= Euclid's algorithm. And $90=16$ in $\Bbb Z/37$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: $90\mod37 =16$, so the answer you found was correct, just not fully reduced.

Comment: Thanks you are right!

Comment: I used the formula A mod B = A + K*B, 90 mod 37 = 90 + k* 37, then  c = -2 got me to 16. Is this the right way to reduce?

Comment: Ya exactly, you got it!

Answer (score 1):

We have $$11x\equiv -9\equiv 28\mod 37$$ so we get
$$x\equiv \frac{28}{11}\equiv \frac{65}{11}\equiv\frac{102}{11}\equiv \frac{139}{11}\equiv \frac{176}{11}\equiv 16\mod 11$$

Comment: We don't need to employ a brute-force search above. Instead we can use [Inverse Reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242). Here the idea is that we seek $\,\color{#c00}k\,$ that makes an *exact* quotient from $\, 28/11 \equiv (28\!+\!37\color{#c00}k)/11,\,$  which is true iff $$\bmod 11\!:\,\ 0\equiv 28\!+\!37k\equiv {-}5\!+\!4k\iff 4k\equiv 5\equiv 16\iff \color{#c00}{k\equiv 4}$$ Therefore $\,x\equiv (28 +37\cdot\color{#c00} 4)/11 \equiv 176/11 \equiv 16$ $\ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

$\bmod 37\!:\,\ x\equiv 90\equiv 16\ $ so both are correct. [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) is simpler:

$\bmod 37\!:\,\ x\equiv\dfrac{-9}{11}\equiv\dfrac{-27}{33}\equiv\dfrac{10}{-4}\equiv\dfrac{5}{{-}2\,}\equiv\dfrac{-32}{-2}\equiv 16$

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for a solution to $11x\equiv-9\pmod{37}$.

First, solve $11x+37y=1$. As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021), we use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&3&2&1&3\\\hline
1&0&1&-2&3&-11\\
0&1&-3&7&-10&37\\
37&11&4&3&1&0
\end{array}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{array}{c}
3\cdot37-10\cdot11=1\\
\Downarrow&\text{multiply by $-9$}\\
90\cdot11\equiv-9\pmod{37}\\
\Downarrow&\text{add $13$ to both sides}\\
16\cdot11+13\equiv4\pmod{37}&90\equiv16\pmod{37}
\end{array}
$$
Therefore, we have
$$
x\equiv16\pmod{37}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Mod 11, it reduces to $2\equiv 4y+4$ and $24=2\cdot11+2=4(5)+4$ which then gets $11x+13=189\implies 11x=176\implies x=16$

Note however, this is just one of infinitely many answers. Incrementing x by 35, and y by 11 yields new answers that work. All the x values fall on the line $35z+16$, all the y values fall on the line $11a+5$