# $6x + 13 = 7 \pmod{24}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$6x + 13 = 7 \pmod{24}$

What method can I use to solve this problem?

I tried with the method I used  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198371/11x-13-equiv-4-mod-37/3198885#3198885) but it won't work because I can't use Euclidean algorithm on this problem.

Comment: There are $4$ values to check $x=0,1,2,3$ after that it repeats.

Comment: This is same as $6x\equiv-6\pmod{24}$. It might help to recall some general theory of solving $ax\equiv b\pmod{m}$. Let $d=\gcd(a,m)$. Recall that $ax\equiv b\pmod{m}$ has a solution iff $d\mid b$. If $d\mid b$, there are $d$ distinct solutions mod $m$, and a unique solution mod $m/d$. First solve $\frac{a}{d}x\equiv \frac{b}{d}\pmod{\frac{m}{d}}$ for $x$ (you should at least be able to do this as $\gcd\left(\frac{a}{d}, \frac{m}{d}\right)=1$). Then if $x_0$ is a solution to this, the $d$ distinct solutions to the original congruence are ($x_0 + k\frac{m}{d}$) mod $m$, for $k=0,1,\ldots, d-1$.

Comment: To write $6x + 13 \equiv 7 \pmod{24}$, type `$6x + 13 \equiv 7 \pmod{24}$`.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $6x+13\equiv7\pmod{24}\iff6x\equiv-6\pmod{6\times4}$.

Answer (score 0):

$x+2=4y+1$ by direct division by 6 when turned to linear polynomial form. Therefore, $x\equiv 3\bmod 4$

Answer (score 0):

$$6x+13\equiv7\pmod{24}\iff 6x+6\equiv0\pmod{24}\iff 24|6x+6\iff 4|x+1$$