# diophantine equation $ 5x + 19y = 100 $ with natural numbers

Tags: diophantine-equations

```
5x + 19y = 100
```

given the constraint that the two variables belong to N

I get the answer:

x = 400 
y = (-100)

I dont know if this is the right asnwer to the question

Comment: There are lots of solutions.  $(x,y)=(1,5)$ for instance.

Comment: Whenever you have an algebra problem and you don't know if an answer is correct , you only need to plug the numbers in and see what happens. What result do you get when you plug the values in?

Comment: my numbers works but do they meat the requirment (given the constraint that the two variables belong to N)

Comment: No, your solution does not work since $-100$ is not a natural number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear diophantine equation $100x - 23y = -19$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67969/linear-diophantine-equation-100x-23y-19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 divides into 19 3 times with remainder 4: 19- 3(5)= 4

4 divides into 5 once with remainder 1: 5- 4= 1

So 5- (19- 3(5))= 4(5)- 1(19)= 1

Multiply by 100: 5(400)- 19(100)= 100.

One solution to 5x + 19y = 100  is x= 400, y= -100.

But x= 400- 19n, y= -100+ 5n is also a solution for any n:
5(400- 19n)+ 19(-100+ 5n)= 5(400)- 19(100)- 95n+ 95n= 100.

y will be positive for any n greater than 20.  In particular, for n= 21, y= -100+ 105= 5.  If n= 21, x= 400- 19(21)= 400- 399= 1.

The only solution with both x and y positive is x= 1, y= 5.

Answer (score 1):

Since $5x$ and $100$ are divisible by $5$, so must $19y$.  Since $19$ is not divisible by $5$, then $y$ must be.  So $y = 5, 10, 15 \ldots$.

Now $5x= 100 - 19y$ has to be positive, so $100 > 19 y$, so $y < 100/19 < 6$.  There for the only possibility is $y=5.$

Comment: can it not be x,y (20, 0)

Comment: Most people use $N$ for $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}.$  If $0$ is included, they call it $N_0.$

Answer (score 1):

Note first that we must have $5\,|\,y$, so write $y=5Y$.  Then we can divide by $5$ to obtain $$x+19Y=20$$

Thus the integer solutions (without attention to signs) are the pairs $(x, 5Y)$ with $x=20-19Y$.

For instance, taking $Y=1$ we get $x=20-19\times 1=1$ hence the solution $(1,5)$.

Taking $Y=2$ we get $x=20-19\times 2=-18$ hence the solution $(-18,10)$.

And so on.

If you require both $x,Y$ to be positive we see that the only solution is $(1,5)$, since $Y>1\implies x= 20-19Y<0$.

To be clear:  the question asked about "natural numbers".  Some people define natural numbers as integers $≥0$, others define it as integers $≥1$.  If you allow $0$ to be a natural number then you must also consider the solution with $Y=0$, hence $(20,0)$.

Comment: can it not be x,y (20, 0)

Comment: This depends on your definition of natural numbers.  For me, a natural number must be $≥1$, so it excludes $0$.  If you allow $0$ then your solution works.  People disagree as to the definition.  I have edited my post to stress this point.

Answer (score 0):

In general for the equation $ax+by=c$ if you have a particular solution $(x_0,y_0)$ then you can do
$$ax+by=c\\ax_0+by_0=c$$ so you get $$a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)=0$$ from which making
$x-x_0=bt$ and $y-y_0=-at$ you get the identity $abt-abt=0$ from which all the solutions (there are infinitely many)
$$x=x_0+bt\\y=y_0-at$$ where $t$ is a parameter taking all integer value. You can discriminate if you want to have only natural numbers (which obviously are in finite number of them).