# How to solve $10x^{39 }+ 8x^{20} + 9x^3 + 7x ≡ 0\pmod {19}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-domain

I guess I'm supposed to solve it with Euclidian ring (or Euclidian domain), but I'm not even sure about that.

$$10x^{39 }+ 8x^{20} + 9x^3 + 7x ≡ 0\pmod {19}$$

I've managed to turn it into $(10x^{19}+8)x^{17}+9)x^2+7)x$ 
But after that I have no clue what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Trial and error works easily.  Keep in mind that $x^{19}=x\pmod {19}$ for all the residues $\pmod {19}$.

Comment: don't know if this helps you, what you can solve it in wolfram alpha

Comment: Formatting note:  you need to use curly brackets for multicharacter exponents.  x^{39} compiles as $x^{39}$, for example.

Comment: Edit question:  I can't sort out if you meant to type $7x$ or $7^x$.  I guessed you meant the former but if I guessed wrong please edit accordingly.  Trial and error is easy with either reading.

Answer (score 1):

Little Fermat says $x^{19}\equiv x\pmod{19}$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\overbrace{\ \ 10x^{39}\ \ }^{\substack{10x^3\\\text{cancels}\\9x^3}}+\overbrace{\ \ \ 8x^{20}\ \ \ }^{8x^2}+9x^3+7x\\
&\equiv8x^2+7x\pmod{19}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
which means $x\equiv0\pmod{19}$ or $x\equiv-\frac78\pmod{19}$

We can compute $\frac18\pmod{19}$ using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm (as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021)):
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&2&2&1&2\\\hline
1&0&1&-2&3&-8\\
0&1&-2&5&-7&19\\
19&8&3&2&1&0\\
\end{array}\tag2
$$
which says that $3\cdot19-7\cdot8=1$; therefore, $\frac18\equiv-7\pmod{19}$.

Applying the result from $(2)$ to the result from $(1)$ gives
$$
x\in\{0,11\}\pmod{19}\tag3
$$

Answer (score 0):

$19$ is prime.

There are no zero divisors in the ring $\mathbb Z_p$

From what you have above either $x\equiv 0 \pmod {19}$ or $(10x^{19}+8)x^{17}+9)x^2+7)\equiv 0\pmod{19}$

What else can we say?  By Fermats little theorem $x^p = x\pmod p$

$10x^{39} + 8x^{20} + 9x^3 + 7x\equiv 10x^3 + 8x^2 + 9x^3 + 7x\equiv (19x^2 +9x + 7)x \pmod {19}$

$19x^2\equiv 0 \pmod {19}$ so we can drop this term.

$9x + 7 \equiv 0\\
18 x + 14 \equiv 0\\
-x + 14 \equiv 0\\
x \equiv 14$

We have two solutions $x\equiv 0, x\equiv 14 \pmod 14$

Comment: There are no solutions to $9x^2+18x+7\equiv 0 \mod {19}$.

Comment: It is $x^{39}$ and not $x^{38}$.

Comment: Thanks to my for the corrections.  This should be better.

Answer (score 0):

By Fermat's Theorem
$$10x^{39}+8x^{20}+9x^3+7x\equiv 10x^3+8x^2+9x^3+7x\equiv 8x^2+7x\equiv 0\;(\textsf{mod}\; 19).$$
Therefore, for 19 being a prime number: $x\equiv 0\;(\textsf{mod}\; 19)$ or $8x+7\equiv 0\;(\textsf{mod}\; 19)\Rightarrow x\equiv -84\equiv 11\;(\textsf{mod}\; 19)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look for the roots of this polynomial in $F := \mathbb{Z} / 19 \mathbb{Z}$. This polynomial can be seen as a polynomial in $F[X]$.
Since $19$ is prime, $F$ is a field. A most enjoyable property of $F$ is that the map $x \mapsto x^{19}$ is the identity. In other words, for any $x \in F$, we have $x^{19} = x$. This allows us to simplify for $x \in F$:

$$\begin{eqnarray} 10x^{39 }+ 8x^{20} + 9x^3 + 7x &=& 10x^{20 }+ 8x^{20} + 9x^3 + 7x \\ =10 x + 8x+ 9x^3 + 7x &=& 9x^3 + 25 x\\ = 9x^3 + 6x\end{eqnarray}$$

Let's factorize this expression : $9 x^3 + 6x = 3 \cdot x \cdot (3x^2 +2)$. Here, we see an obvious solution, $0$ and maybe two other solutions that correspond to the solutions of $3x^2 +2 = 0$.

Now we want the leading coefficient to be $1$, so we multiply by the inverse of $3$ in $F$ : $13$.

$$3x^2 +2 = 0\Longleftrightarrow x^2 + 16= 0 \\ \Longleftrightarrow x^2 = -16 \\ \Longleftrightarrow x^2 = 3$$

Since $3$ isn't a square in $F$, $0$ is the only solution.