# GCD of $n^2-3n-1$ and $n-4$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

$n$ is a natural number and after trying the division algorithm

$$\gcd(n^2-3n-1,n-4)=\gcd(n-4,n-1)=\gcd(n-1,-3)=\gcd(n-1,3)$$

For the last part I'm not sure whether it does equal to $\gcd(n-1,3)$.
If yes, then should I take the cases where $n$ is $3k+i, 0\le i\le2$?

Comment: The answers are "yes" and "yes", but please fix the title of your question. (There is no such thing as "greatest common *multiple*".)

Comment: @StinkingBishop What you fail to reailize is that mathSE reviewers have it all too easy.  They should have to work to decipher the question (re OP wants lcm or gcd), before answering it.  That is where the real *artistry* lies.

Comment: @user2661923 I've seen worse cases than this, sadly.

Comment: On the off chance that you wanted the lcm, you have the formula for $~a,b ~\in ~\mathbb{Z^+}$ of $$\text{lcm}(a,b) ~=~ \frac{a \times b}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}.$$

Comment: $\gcd(n-1,3)\,$ is $\,3\,$ if $\,3\mid n-1,\,$ else the gcd $=1\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

1. If you write as follows $$\gcd(n-4, n-1) = \gcd(n-4, 3) = \gcd(n-1, 3)$$ you will be sure i.e

- $n-1 - (n-4) = 3$
- $n-4 + 3 = n-1$

2. Yes, you can see those cases.

Comment: So for each case :$n=3k \Rightarrow gcd(3k-1,3)=1,n=3k+1 \Rightarrow gcd(3k,3)=3, n=3k+2 \Rightarrow gcd(3k+1,3)=1$ ?

Comment: @user3133165 Yes, right.

Answer (score 0):

After help from the comments and @VIVID.

$$\gcd(n^2-3n-1,n-4)=\gcd(n-4,n-1)=\gcd(n-1,-3)=\gcd(n-1,3)$$

The cases of $n$ are $n=3k,n=3k+1,n=3k+2$ for a natural $k$, will be:

$n=3k \Rightarrow \gcd(3k-1,3)=1$

$n=3k+1 \Rightarrow \gcd(3k,3)=3$

$n=3k+2 \Rightarrow \gcd(3k+1,3)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Using [this implementation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021) of the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), rotated $90^{\large\circ}$ and applied to polynomials, gives
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\color{#00F}{n^2-3n-1}&1&0\\
\color{#00F}{n-4}&0&1\\
\color{#090}{n-1}&\color{#C00}{1}&\color{#C00}{-n}&n\\
\color{#090}{-3}&\color{#C00}{-1}&\color{#C00}{n+1}&1
\end{array}
$$
which says that
$$
\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\color{#C00}{1}&\color{#C00}{-n}\\\color{#C00}{-1}&\color{#C00}{n+1}
\end{bmatrix}}^{\det=1}
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{#00F}{n^2-3n-1}\\\color{#00F}{n-4}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\color{#090}{n-1}\\\color{#090}{-3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which means any integer linear combination of $n-1$ and $3$ is an integer linear combination of $n^2-3n-1$ and $n-4$ and vice-versa (since the determinant of the matrix is $1$). This means that
$$
\gcd\left(n^2-3n-1,n-4\right)=\gcd(n-1,3)
$$