# Does anyone know of a much faster way to solve this polynomial question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

A monic cubic $p(x) $ is divided by $(x^2 +x +1)$ and the remainder is $(2x+3)$. When $p(x)$ is divided by $x(x+3)$, the remainder is $5(x+1)$. Find $p(x)$

So the way I solved it was through using long division - as you can imagine very lengthy, and not very efficient in exam situations. I then equated the remainders with the given remainders. However, in an exam situation, would there be an even faster way? I am open to suggestions.

Comment: isnt the degree of p(x) given?

Comment: sorry , i forgot to write cubic

Comment: I suspect that long division is the *intended* solution.  Typically, in an exam or homework setting, you are not expected to invent a new approach.  Instead, the problem(s) are usually designed to reinforce the concepts that you've been taught.  Therefore, if you hadn't already been taught an alternative approach, the problem is probably designed to test your inherent understanding of polynomial long division.  Therefore, the approach that you took was probably the intended approach.

Comment: but just for practice at home, I wonder if there is a faster method to save time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is a trick: as the polynomial has leading coefficient 1 and degree 3 we have $$p(x)=(x+K)(x^2+x+1)+2x+3$$  Now use the fact that $$p(x)=x(x+3)g(x)+5(x+1)$$ $$p(0)=5(0+1)=5$$ $$K=2$$

Comment: Magnificent. Such a concise solution. However, this method seems to only work given a specific set of conditions right? ie it will not work all the time

Comment: @user71207 maybe not ,sometimes other tricks may work,this is is good as long as the degree of polynomial is close to the one dividing

Comment: (+1) This is certainly quite simple. It is tailored to this particular case, but that is something shared by most short-cuts.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a quicker way, but it is systematic and will work in all cases where the two moduli have no common factors. Hopefully, it also might make the use of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm with the Chinese Remainder Theorem more transparent.

---

We want
$$
\begin{align}
p(x)&\equiv2x+3&&\pmod{x^2+x+1}\tag{1a}\\
p(x)&\equiv5x+5&&\pmod{x^2+3x}\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
so we apply the Extended Euclidean Algorithm (as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021) and adapted to polynomials) to $x^2+3x$ and $x^2+x+1$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
x^2+3x&1&0\\
x^2+x+1&0&1\\
2x-1&1&-1&1\\
\frac74&-\frac{2x+3}4&\frac{2x+7}4&\frac{2x+3}4
\end{array}\tag2
$$
Thus, we get
$$
(2x+7)\left(x^2+x+1\right)-(2x+3)\left(x^2+3x\right)=7\tag3
$$
So we have
$$
-\frac{(2x+3)\left(x^2+3x\right)}7\equiv\left\{
\begin{align}
&1&&\pmod{x^2+x+1}\\
&0&&\pmod{x^2+3x}
\end{align}
\right.\tag4
$$
and
$$
\frac{(2x+7)\left(x^2+x+1\right)}7\equiv\left\{
\begin{align}
&0&&\pmod{x^2+x+1}\\
&1&&\pmod{x^2+3x}\\
\end{align}
\right.\tag5
$$
Adding $2x+3$ times $(4)$ to $5x+5$ times $(5)$ yields one solution to $(1)$:
$$
\begin{align}
&\overbrace{(5x+5)\frac{(2x+7)\left(x^2+x+1\right)}7}^{\substack{0&\pmod{x^2+x+1}\\5x+5&\pmod{x^2+3x}}}\overbrace{-(2x+3)\frac{(2x+3)\left(x^2+3x\right)}7}^{\substack{2x+3&\pmod{x^2+x+1}\\0&\pmod{x^2+3x}}}\\
&=\frac{6x^4+31x^3+45x^2+53x+35}7\tag6
\end{align}
$$
The Chinese Remainder Theorem says that this is the solution mod $\left(x^2+x+1\right)\left(x^2+3x\right)$, so we can subtract $\frac67$ of the modulus to get
$$
\begin{align}
p(x)
&=\frac{6x^4+31x^3+45x^2+53x+35}7-\frac67\left(x^2+x+1\right)\left(x^2+3x\right)\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x^3+3x^2+5x+5}\tag7
\end{align}
$$