# showing that if the $\text{ord}_p(a) = h$ modulo p is even, then $a^{\frac{h}{2}}=-1 \pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory

I am not sure how to tackle this problem and yes it is a homework problem. 
Here is what I have. I know that $\text{ord}(a) = h$ and h is even so $h = 2 \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$. I also know Euler's criterion which states that $$a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = -1 \pmod{p}$$ if there are no integers $x$ which satisfy $x^2 = a \pmod{p}$. 
So my steps are

$a^h = (x^2)^h = 1 \pmod{p}$ which implies $p | x^{2h} - 1$. I am now stuck, am I in the right direction? Please let me know a hint.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: $\,ord_7(3)=6\,\,,\,\,3^{6/3}=3^2=0\pmod 3\,$....what am I missing?

Comment: The exact problem from the book (Niven) is: Prove that if $a$ belongs to the exponent $h$ modulo $p$ and if $h$ is even, then $a^{\frac{h}{2}} = -1 \pmod{p}$

Comment: Where *exactly* in that book?...I'm guessing you mean the book by Niven, Zuckerman and Montgomery...?

Comment: Yes. Number 15 on page 106 - 5th edition, chapter 2.8 under Congruences

Comment: Also, i found your mistake - Its supposed to be $3^{6/2} = 3^3 = 27 = -1 \pmod{7}$

Comment: Oh, I see it now! You have a huge typo: it must be that you should prove $\,a^{h/2}=-1\pmod p\,$ ,. **not** $\,3\,$ !

Comment: I fixed it. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem must be to show $\,a^{h/2}=-1\pmod p\,$ , but this follows almost immediately from:

$$ord_p(a)=h\Longleftrightarrow a^h=1\pmod p\,\,\,\wedge\,\,\,a^m\neq 1\,\,\,\forall\,m<h\Longrightarrow $$

$$a^{h/2}\,\,\,\text{is a square root of 1 different from 1 itself}\Longrightarrow a^{h/2}=-1$$

since the only square roots of unit in any field are $\,\pm 1\,$ (and not in any case they're different...)

Comment: could you explain the last line, ie why $m < h$ implies $a^{h/2}$ is a square root of 1 and more specifically why it can't be one itself?

Comment: nvmd I got it. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ p\!:\ 0 \equiv a^h\!-1\equiv (a^{h/2}\!-1)(a^{h/2}\!+1)\Rightarrow a^{h/2}\!+1 \equiv 0,\:$ by cancelling $\rm\,a^{h/2}\!-1$ $(\not\equiv 0,\,$ else the order of $\rm\,a\,$ is $\rm\le h/2).\:$ Elements $\ne 0$ are invertible (so cancellable) because $\rm\,\Bbb Z/p\,$ is a field.

**Remark** $\ $ With $\rm\:x = a^{h/2},\:$ the above proof shows that $\rm\,x\not\equiv 1,\ x^2\equiv 1\:\Rightarrow\: x\equiv -1,\:$ i.e. the only square roots of $1$ are $\pm 1.\,$ This is a special case of the fact that of the fact that a nonzero polynomial over a field (or domain) has no more roots than its degree (a property which characterizes integral domains among rings). Indeed, some algorithms for factoring an integer $\rm\,n\,$ work by searching $\rm\,mod\ n\,$ for a square root of $1$ that is *nontrivial*, i.e. $\ne \pm1.\:$ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/33028/23500) for further discussion on such.