# If $p$ is an odd prime and $a$ is a positive integer not divisible by p, then the congruence has either no solution or 2 incongruent solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My question is as follows:

> Show that if $p$ is an odd prime and $a$ is a positive integer not divisible by p, then the congruence $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$ has either no solution or exactly two incongruent solutions.

Now, I can show that the congruence cannot have exactly one solution.  Suppose $z$ is a solution. Then $z^2 \equiv (-z)^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$, and thus, $-z$ is also a solution.  If $z \equiv -z \pmod{p}$, then $2z \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, so it must be that either $p$|$2$ or $p$|$z$.  But since $p$ is odd and prime, $p$ cannot divide 2, and if $p$|$z$, then $p$|$z^2$ and so $a \equiv z^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, which implies $p$|$a$, a contradiction.  Thus, $z$ and $-z$ are incongruent modulo p.

Now, if I can show that the congruence has no more than 2 solutions, then I believe the problem is solved.  How can I demonstrate this?

Comment: Let $x$ be a solution. Then you know $x^2 - z^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Does that ring a bell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\,b\,$ is a root then $\!\bmod p\!:\ b^2\equiv a\,$ so $\,x^2-a\equiv x^2-b^2\equiv (x\!-\!b)(x\!+\!b),\,$ so if $\,c\,$ is also  a root then $\,(c\!-\!b)(c\!+\!b)\equiv 0\,$ so $\,p\mid(c\!-\!b)(c\!+\!b)\,\color{#c00}{\rm \overset{F}\Rightarrow}\, p\mid c\!-\!b\ $ or $\ p\mid c\!+\!b,\,$ so $\,c\equiv \pm b,\,$ by $\rm\color{#c00}{F}$ = FTA = *existence & uniqueness of prime factorizations* (or by [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162373/242) or closely related results).

**Or** if $\,c\not\equiv \pm b\,$ is a root then $\,(x-b)(x+b) \equiv (x-c)(x+c),\,$ contra  polynomials over a field have *unique prime factorizations* (Euclidean domains are UFDs). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37519/242) for more on this view.

**Remark** $\ $ More generally over a field (or domain) such as  $\,\Bbb Q,\Bbb R,\Bbb C,\Bbb Z_p,\,$   iterating the Factor Theorem shows that  nonzero polynomial has no more roots than its degree (in fact this property is *equivalent* to the coefficient ring being a domain, i.e. $\,a,b\neq 0\Rightarrow ab\neq 0).\,$ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) for a proof.