# Last 3 digits of $3^{999}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion

I know that it's $3^{999} \mod 1000$ and since $\varphi(1000) = 400$ and $3^{400}\equiv1 \mod1000$ it will be equivalent to $3^{199} \mod 1000$ but what should I do from then? Or am I wrong about this from the start?

Comment: Use Chinese remainder theorem for this.

Comment: $3^{999 }\equiv 3^{4\cdot249}\cdot 3 \equiv 3\pmod{8} $.

Comment: See also [How do I compute $a^c \bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228) and similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) will be beneficial here as 
$\displaystyle\lambda(1000)=100$

$$\implies 3^{100n}\equiv1^n\pmod{1000}\equiv1$$ for any integer $n$

As $(3,1000)=1,$ this implies $$3^{100n-1}\equiv3^{-1}$$

As $\displaystyle 999\equiv-1\pmod{1000}\implies3^{-1}\equiv-333\equiv1000-333$

Comment: @Downvoter, Please pinpoint the mistake

Comment: Sorry about the bump. I mistakenly downvoted this today (when this was linked to a new questions), so I had to make a fake edit to be able to upvote instead.

Comment: @jyrki been there done that.  I've lost count of how many times I have put in a "the" or changed the spelling of a word just to get rid of an unintended downvote .

Answer (score 6):

To know $3^n\bmod 1000$ it is enough to know $3^n\bmod 8$ and $3^n\bmod 125$. From $3^2\equiv 1\pmod 8$ we conclude $3^{1000}\equiv 1\pmod 8$.
From $\phi(125)=100$, we conclude $3^{1000}=(3^{100})^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{125}$. Therefore $3^{1000}\equiv 1\pmod {1000}$. This implies $3^{999}\equiv 667\pmod{1000}$

Answer (score 3):

$$3^{999}=3(10-1)^{499}$$

Now, $$(10-1)^{499}\equiv-1+\binom{499}110^1-\binom{499}210^2\pmod{1000}$$

Again, $\displaystyle\binom{499}1=499\equiv-1\pmod{100}\implies\binom{499}110^1\equiv-10\pmod{100\cdot10}$

and $\displaystyle\binom{499}2=\frac{499\cdot498}2\equiv\frac{(-1)(2)}2\pmod{10}\equiv1\implies\binom{499}210^2\equiv100\pmod{10\cdot100}$

$\displaystyle\implies(10-1)^{499}\equiv-1-10-100\pmod{1000}\equiv-111$

The rest should be easy to deal with

Comment: I'm a bit curious as to why you posted this as a different answer instead of editing your earlier one. My inclination is to downvote this, because I view the practice as impolite *rep farming*, but may be I have missed something?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Have you recognized the difference in the approach?

Answer (score 2):

Note $\,\ \phi(8)=4\mid\phi(125)=\color{#0a0}{100},\,$  so using this as a common period in [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242)

thus $\ {\rm mod}\ 8,\,125\!:\ 3^{999}\equiv  (3^{\large \color{#0a0}{100}})^{10}/3\equiv 1/3\ $ by [Euler's $\phi$ Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)  and $\,(3,8)\!=\!1\!=\!(3,125).$

[thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) $\ {\rm mod}\ 8\cdot 125\!:\ 3^{999}\equiv  \color{#c00}1/3\equiv \color{#c00}{-999}/3 \equiv -333\,\ $ by  $\,\ \color{#c00}{1 \equiv -999} \pmod {\!1000 }$

**Remark** $ $ The method above easily yields the following generaization of the Euler-Fermat theorem (see also [Carmichael's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/786547/242))

**Theorem** $\  $ Suppose that $\ m\in \mathbb N\ $ has the prime factorization $\:m = p_1^{e_{1}}\cdots\:p_k^{e_k}\ $ and suppose that for all $\,i,\,$  $\ e\ge e_i\ $ and $\ \phi(p_i^{e_{i}})\mid f.\ $ Then $\ m\mid a^e(a^f-1)\ $ for all $\: a\in \mathbb Z.$

**Proof** $\ $ If $\ p_i\mid a\ $ then $\:p_i^{e_{i}}\mid a^e\ $ by $\ e_i \le e.\: $ Else $\:a\:$ is coprime to $\: p_i\:$ so by Euler's phi theorem, $\!\bmod q = p_i^{e_{i}}\!: \ a^{\phi(q)}\equiv 1\,$ [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) $\,a^f\equiv 1\, $ by $\: \phi(q)\mid f.\ $  Since all $\ p_i^{e_{i}}\,$ divide $\, a^e (a^f - 1)\ $ so too does their product $\,m\,$ by [lcm = product for coprimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/696331/242), or by unique prime factorization.

**Examples** $\ $ You can find many illuminating examples in prior questions, e.g. below

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$24\mid a^3(a^2-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408201/242)

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$40\mid a^3(a^4-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/637468/242)

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$88\mid a^5(a^{20}\!-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1316052/242)

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$6p\mid a\,b^p - b\,a^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2003925/242)

Answer (score 2):

Start with $3^4=80+1$. Raise to the 25th power with the Binomial Theorem:

$3^{100}=(80+1)^{25}=80^{25}+...(2300×80^3)+(300×80^2)+(25×80)+1$

The coefficient $300$ is of course obtained from $(25×24)/(1×2)$ after canceling common factors, similarly for $2300=(25×24×23)/(1×2×3)$ in the previous term.  The terms through $2300×80^3$ are multiples of 1000 because of the power of 80 they contain, and the next two terms are easily calculated to be multiples of 1000 as well.  We are left with $3^{100}\equiv 1 \bmod 1000$ from which:

$3^{999}\equiv 1^{10}×3^{-1}\equiv (2001/3)=667\bmod 1000$.

Answer (score 2):

Giving some structure to the [answer by @fruitbat](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3564001/206402) that is effectively using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), this answer ignores the advantages that are possible by the consideration of modular order (cycling of values) to focus on an example of what is possible if using a larger or less convenient modulus:

So, here's a tabular form of exponentiation by squaring:

- starting with the exponent, work **down the left-hand column**, subtracting $1$ from odd numbers and halving even numbers. then
- starting with the base, work **up the right-hand column**. multiplying by the base, $3$, or squaring as appropriate, taking the modulus each time.

$\newcommand{oddnote}{{x \mathit{\text{ odd, }{\times}\text{base}}}}
\newcommand{evennote}{{x \mathit{\text{ even, square}}}}$
\begin{array}{c|c}
x & 3^x \bmod 1000 & \mathit{\text{notes}}\\\hline
\bbox[yellow]{\;999\;} & \fbox{667} & \oddnote \\ 
998 & 889 & \evennote \\ 
499 & 667 & \oddnote \\ 
498 & 889 & \evennote  \\ 
249 & 83 & \oddnote \\ 
248 & 361 & \evennote  \\ 
124 & 481 & \evennote  \\ 
62 & 809 & \evennote  \\ 
31 & 947 & \oddnote \\ 
30 & 649 & \evennote  \\ 
15 & 907 & \oddnote \\ 
14 & 969 & \evennote  \\ 
7 & 187 & \oddnote \\ 
6 & 729 & \evennote  \\ 
3 & 27 & \oddnote \\ 
2 & 9 & \evennote \\ 
1 & \bbox[yellow]{\;3\;} & \mathit{\text{base}} \\ 
\phantom{\large\Rightarrow}\Downarrow\Downarrow\underset{\large\Rightarrow}{}
&\underset{\large\Rightarrow}{}\Uparrow\Uparrow\phantom{\large\Rightarrow} \\
\end{array}

Comment: Not the best method for this specific problem, but a good template for the squaring-based method of exponentiation.

Comment: thanks @OscarLanzi, that's exactly what I was aiming for it to be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know number theory and lack math backgorund to understand any of the given answers. I came with this basic math solution while trying to answer a duplicate question.
$$
3^{999}=3^{512}\times3^{256}\times3^{128}\times3^{64}\times3^{32}\times3^{4}\times3^{2}\times3\\
\quad=9^{256}\times9^{128}\times9^{64}\times9^{32}\times9^{16}\times9^{2}\times9\times3\\
=81^{128}\times81^{64}\times81^{32}\times81^{16}\times81^{8}\times{81}\times9\times3
$$
From now on calculating only the last three digits, as $81^2$ exceeds three digits.
$$
3^{999}=..561^{64}\times..561^{32}\times..561^{16}\times...561^{8}\times..561^{4}\times{81}\times9\times3\\=..721^{32}\times..721^{16}\times..721^{8}\times.721^{4}\times..721^{2}\times81\times9\times3\\
=..841^{16}\times..841^{8}\times..841^{4}\times..841^{2}\times..841\times81\times9\times3\\
=..281^{8}\times..281^{4}\times..281^{2}\times..281\times..841\times81\times9\times3\\
=..961^{4}\times..961^{2}\times..961\times..281\times..841\times81\times9\times3\\
=..521^{2}\times..521\times..961\times..281\times..841\times81\times9\times3\\
=..441\times..521\times..961\times..281\times..841\times81\times9\times3\\
=(..441\times..521)\times(..961\times..281)\times(..841\times81)\times(9\times3)\\
=..761\times..041\times..121\times27\\
=..201\times..267\\
=..667
$$

Comment: Basically a form of [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Answer (score 0):

Simple computation, and the fact that $\phi(8)=4$, gives
$$
\begin{align}
3^{999}
&\equiv3^3\\
&\equiv3\pmod8\tag1
\end{align}
$$
The [square and multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm, and the fact that $\phi(125)=100$, gives
$$
\begin{align}
3^{999}
&\equiv3^{99}\\
&\equiv42\pmod{125}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
The [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021), gives
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&15&1&1&1&2\\\hline
1&0&1&-1&2&-3&8\\
0&1&-15&16&-31&47&-125\\
125&8&5&3&2&1&0
\end{array}\tag3
$$
which says that
$$
47\cdot8-3\cdot125=1\tag4
$$
Equation $(4)$ implies both
$$
\begin{align}
-375&\equiv1\pmod8\\
-375&\equiv0\pmod{125}
\end{align}\tag5
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
376&\equiv0\pmod8\\
376&\equiv1\pmod{125}
\end{align}\tag6
$$
Thus, to satisfy $(1)$ and $(2)$, we compute
$$
\begin{align}
3^{999}
&\equiv42\cdot376-3\cdot375\\
&\equiv667&\pmod{1000}\tag7
\end{align}
$$