# How to find the last five digits of $3^{1234567}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If it's $2/3$ digits I could easily do that. But when I'm using Euler theorem, I still have to compute $3^{34567} \mod 100000$, which is still hard.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Solve $x\pmod {5^5}$ and $x\pmod {2^5}$ sparately.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789050/last-3-digits-of-3999

Answer (score 1):

It happens that $3$ has order $8\bmod 2^5=32$, so
$$3^{1234567}\equiv 3^{1234567\bmod 8}=3^7\mod 2^5.$$

As to  the congruence class $\bmod 5^5=3125$, we have $\varphi(5^5)=4\cdot 5^4=2500$, so
$$3^{1234567}\equiv 3^{1234567\bmod 2500}=3^{2067}\mod 5^5.$$
This requires $11$ squarings and $3$ multiplications mod. $3125$ by the *fast exponentiation algorithm*.

Once you have the powers mod $32$ and mod $3125$, you can readily deduce the  power mod $100{,}000$ by the explicit *Chinese remainder theorem*.