# A nonzero polynomial over a domain has no more roots than its degree

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was given this proposition but I was never able to prove it. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Let $f$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$, where $p$ is prime. Then $f$ has at most $\deg f$ roots.

Comment: The coefficient ring is contained in a field, $\Bbb Q_p$, (since $p$ is prime, $\Bbb Q_p$ is a field) of characteristic $0$ when $p$ is prime, and all characteristic $0$ polynomials are separable. (I'm using the characterization of separable as irreducible factors have no multiple roots)

Comment: Alternatively, we know that there are roots out there "somewhere" (i.e. in an algebraic closure) so we can use the fact that polynomials over a field are a Euclidean domain, hence have unique factorization, and the irreducibles in an algebraically closed field are exactly the monomials.

Comment: @AdamHughes: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is already a field when $p$ is a prime.

Comment: What? Oh you mean $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, not $\Bbb Z_p$, the former is the field with $p$ elements, the latter is the $p$-adic numbers, though I know some use the latter notation for the former some times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients in any field can have at most $n$ roots, because $X-\alpha$ is a factor of $f$ whenever $\alpha$ is a root, and the polynomial ring is a UFD.

As a consequence, a polynomial with coefficients in any integral domain can have at most $n$ roots: just consider the roots in the fraction field. (In fact, this property characterizes integral domains.)

Comment: This doesn't require using that the polynomial ring is a UFD, but only the much simpler fact that $\,x - \alpha\,$ is prime $(\!\iff\!$ the coefficient ring is a domain) - see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,f\ne 0\,$ has $\:\!\deg f =n\,$ distinct roots $\,r_i$ then inductively applying the  Factor Theorem (as below) shows $\,f = c(x\!-\!r_1)\cdots (x\!-\!r_n),\,$ so  $\ r\ne r_i\,\Rightarrow\, f(r)= c(r\!-\!r_1)\cdots (r\!-\!r_n) \ne 0\,$ since all factors $\ne 0,\,$ and $\,\Bbb Z_p\,$ is an integral domain. Thus $\,f\,$ has at most $\,n\,$ roots.

---

**Alternatively** $\,f(r_i)= 0 \,\Rightarrow\, x-r_i \mid f(x).\,$ Being divisible by the nonassociate *primes* $\,x-r_i\,$ it follows $\,f\,$ is divisible by their [lcm = product,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/696331/242) so there are at most $\,\deg(f)\,$ factors ($\leftrightarrow$ roots). (Recall $\,x-r\,$ is prime in $\,R[x]\iff R[x]/(x-r)\cong R\,$ is a domain).

---

**Bifactor Theorem** $\ $ Let $\rm\,a,b\in R,\,$ a commutative ring, and $\rm\:f\in R[x]\:$ a polynomial over $\,\rm R.\,$
If $\rm\ \color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b}\ $ is $\,\color{#c00}{\rm cancellable}\,$ in $\rm\,R\,$ (i.e. not a zero-divisor) $ $ then

$$\rm f(a) = 0 = f(b)\ \iff\ f\, =\, (x\!-\!a)(x\!-\!b)\ h\ \ for\ \ some\ \ h\in R[x],$$

hence by induction $\rm \,(x\!-\!a)^k\mid f,\ g\mid f\,\Rightarrow\, (x\!-\!a)^k g\mid f\ $ **if** $\rm\,\color{#0a0}{g(a)}\,$ is $\rm\color{#c00}{cancellable}$.

**Proof** $\,\ (\Leftarrow)\,$ clear. $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ Applying  [Factor Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) twice, while canceling $\rm\: \color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b},$

$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm\:f(b)= 0 &\ \Rightarrow\ &\rm f(x)\, =\, (x\!-\!b)\,g(x)\ \ for\ \ some\ \ g\in R[x]\\[.1em]
\rm f(a) = (\color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b})\,g(a) = 0 &\color{#c00}\Rightarrow&\rm g(a)\, =\, 0\,\ \Rightarrow\ g(x) \,=\, (x\!-\!a)\,h(x)\ \ for\ \ some\ \ h\in R[x]\\[.1em]
&\Rightarrow&\rm f(x)\, =\, (x\!-\!b)\,g(x) \,=\, (x\!-\!b)(x\!-\!a)\,h(x)\end{eqnarray}$$

The claimed induction: $ $ let $\,\rm P_{j}\,$ denote $\rm\,\color{#08f}{(x\!-\!a)^{j}\:\!g}\mid f.\,$ Base case: $\,\rm P_0\,$ is true by hypothesis. Inductive step: suppose $\rm P_n$ is true, and $\,\rm n <\color{darkorange} k.\,$ Then $\rm\,(x\!-\!a)^{n+1}\mid (x\!-\!a)^k\mid f,\,$ i.e.

$\rm (x\!-\!a)^{n+1}\!\mid \color{#08f}{(x\!-\!a)^ng}\,h\Rightarrow x\!-\!a\mid g\:\!h\Rightarrow \color{#0a0}{g(a)} h(a)\!=\!0\color{#c00}\Rightarrow h(a)\!=\!0\Rightarrow x\!-\!a\mid h$

so $\rm\,h = (x\!-\!a)\bar h\,$ so $\rm\,f = (x\!-\!a)^{n+1}g\bar h,\,$ i.e. $\,\rm P_n\Rightarrow P_{n+1},\,$ so $\rm \,P_n\,$ is true for $\,\rm n={\color{darkorange} k}$.

**Remark** $\ $ The theorem  may fail when $\rm\ \color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b}\ $ is *not* $\rm\color{#c00}{cancelable}$ (i.e. is a zero-divisor), e.g.

$$\rm mod\ 8\!:\,\ f(x)=x^2\!-1\,\Rightarrow\,f(3)\equiv 0\equiv f(1)\ \ but\ \  x^2\!-1\not\equiv (x\!-\!3)(x\!-\!1)\equiv x^2\!-4x+3$$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) for the simpler case when the coefficient ring is an integral domain (e.g. a field), and further elaboration.

Comment: i get all of it except for the deduction $(x - a)^{n + 1} \mid (x - a)^n g h \implies x - a \mid gh$. how do you cancel $(x - a)^n$ from both sides? **edit** i guess this follows from the fact that $(x - a)^n$ is monic?

Comment: @BD107 It's standard *divisibility cancellation* (of a cancellable element $\,a),\,$ i.e. $\,ab\mid ac \Rightarrow a\mid c\,$ by cancelling $\,a\,$ from $\,abd = ac.\,$ Monic polynomials $\,a\,$ are cancellable since multiplying by them can't decrease the degree, so $\,ad=0\Rightarrow d=0,\,$ so $\,ab=ac\Rightarrow a(b\!-\!c)=0\Rightarrow b\!-\!c=0\Rightarrow b=c.\ \ $

Comment: yup; got it; that's what i was expecting; thanks.

Comment: @BD107 When $\,g(a)\,$ is a unit this implies  $\,g(x)\,$ is coprime to $\,x\!-\!a\,$ by  $\,(x\!-\!a,g(x))=(x\!-\!a,g(a)) = (1),\,$ [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3555162/242) $\,g(x)\,$ is coprime to $\,(x\!-\!a)^k\,$ so by [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242) $\,(x\!-\!a)^k\!\mid gh\!=\!f\Rightarrow (x\!-\!a)^k\!\mid h\Rightarrow (x\!-\!a)^kg\mid f.\,$ We can reduce the Theorem to this case by passing to the [total fraction ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ring_of_fractions), which adjoins inverses for all cancellable elements.

Comment: i.e. Euclid's Lemma $\Rightarrow$ [LCM = product for coprimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/696331/242) $\ $ @BD107 $\ \ $