# please clarify this proof from gelfands algebra text.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem : numbers 1 and 2 are roots of polynomial P. prove P is divisible by (x-1)(x-2)
given solution:
       since 1 is a root,
         P= (x-1)Q  for some Q. substituting 2 for x in the equality (WHY?) we find that 2 is a root of Q (HOW?). so Q = (x-2) . R for some R. therfore P = (x-1)(x-2)R.

substituting 2 for x i get P=Q but why is 2 a root of Q? is there a reason for substituting 2.

Comment: No, you get $\ 0 = P(2) = (2-1)Q(2) = 0\,$ so $\,Q(2) = 0\,$ so $\,Q(x) = (x-2)R(x)\ $ therefore $\ P(x) = (x-1)Q(x) = (x-1)(x-2)R(x).\ $ Generally this works f the difference of the roots is *cancellable*, see the [BiFactor Theorem.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/868550/242)

Answer (score 0):

Note that, since $2$ is a root of $P$, this means that $P\left(2\right)=0$. Since $P=\left(x-1\right)Q$, we then have that $0=P\left(2\right)=Q\left(2\right)$, meaning that $Q\left(2\right)=0$, which, by definition, means that $2$ is a root of $Q$.