# Proof verification: any n-th order complex polynomial has at most n distinct roots

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification

Here is a proof I came up with in the exam I just took. But I suspect there may be some issues since I think it seems too simple.

> **Proof**
>   Let $p_n(x)$ denote a complex polynomial of order $n$ (coefficients from $\mathbb C$), and suppose $p_n(x)$ has $s$ distinct roots ($s>n$). And let 
>   $$q_s(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{s}(x-x_i)$$
>   where $x_i$ ($i=1,2,\cdots,s$) is one root for $p_n(x)$. *Therefore, $q_s(x)$ must divide $p_n(x)$* (**is it sufficient to say this?**), i.e., 
>   $$q_s(x)\mid p_n(x)$$
>   which requires 
>   $$\deg(q_s(x))\le\deg(p_n(x))$$
>   or
>   $$s\le n$$
>   which contradicts the hypothesis. So the original statement is right.

Since this question appeared at the end of my exam, I think it wouldn't be this easy to do. Maybe there are indeed some issues in my proof? Can you point it out, or verify that my proof is just ok? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean *distinct* roots?

Comment: @BillDubuque oh yes.. apologies for my poor english.

Comment: You must specify the coefficient ring, e.g. $\,x^2-1\,$ has $4$ roots $\,x\equiv \pm1,\pm3$ over $\,\Bbb Z_8 = $ integers mod $8$.

Comment: @BillDubuque the coefficients are picked from $\mathbb C$, I'll add it to my post.

Comment: Yes, then a simple induction using the Factor Theorem can prove what you claim. Take note where the proof cancels differences of distinct roots $\,x_i - x_j$ in order for the induction to work. That's why the above case fails, because $\,\Bbb Z_8$ has nonzero elements that are not cancellable, i.e. it is not an integral domain, e.g. $\,2\cdot 4 = 0\ \ $ Post a proof as an answer and we can give you feedback on it.

Comment: @BillDubuque ... I don't quite understand how things in that $\mathbb Z_8$ work. It's not even a field after all.

Comment: That's ok, in your case you only need to understand how they work in the field $\,\Bbb C,\,$ where $\, a\neq 0,\ ab = 0\,\Rightarrow\, b = 0,\,$ since you can multiply by $\,a^{-1}\,$ to cancel $\,a.\ $ Do you see how to do the inductive proof that $\ q\mid p ?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque thank u !  Then I don't have to worry over that and can put my mind  at rest:)

Comment: But you cannot simply *claim* that $\,q\mid p.\,$ That requires *proof.* As the example I gave shows, it can fail in other rings.

Comment: @BillDubuque well I deemed it to be just too trivial to prove.. And to be honest, I don't know how ( for the exam I would  have done it if I could)

Comment: The argument is either incomplete or incorrect without a proof of that claim. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/868550/242) for one way to do the proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque This answer is for $\mathbb Z_p$?

Comment: The question is about the field $\,\Bbb Z_p\,$ but the answer works in any field, or any integral domain, i.e. any ring where $\, ab = 0\,\Rightarrow\, a=0\,$ or $\,b = 0.\,$ In fact a ring $R$ is an integral domain $\iff$ this property holds true, i.e. nonzero polynomials $f$ with coefficients in $R$ have no more than $\,\deg f\,$ roots.