# Congruence mod $p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

I need a proof for the following:

Suppose that $p$ is an odd prime. If $(a, p) = 1$, then $x^2 = a \pmod p$ either has exactly $2$ solutions or has no solutions within $\textrm{crs}/p$.

I can come up with a lot of examples that work, but I am having trouble with the proof.

Comment: The polynomial $x^2-a$ over the finite field $\mathbb F_p$ is separable.  In other words look up the condition for a polynomial to have a multiple root.  You'll see for $p$ odd the quadratic never does.

Comment: Just to be clear: by $(a, p) = 1$ you are referring to the Legendre symbol and not $\gcd(a, p) = 1$, right?

Comment: @AlonsodelArte No -- that would imply there is always at least one solution.

Comment: @user31415 So that's a yes to GCD and a no to Legendre?

Comment: @AlonsodelArte right. The $\gcd(a,p)=1$ is there because if we had $p\mid a$, then $a\equiv 0\pmod {p}$ and so there is a unique (not two, not zero) solution $x\equiv 0$.

Comment: @user31415 Then I encourage Dillon to rewrite as "$\gcd(a, p) = 1$." I do know that $(a/p)$ would be more conclusively the Legendre symbol, but it doesn't rule out the possibility he meant to type a slash but typed a comma instead.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte $(a,b)$ to denote $\gcd(a,b)$ is conventional and usual. Whereas I've never seen anyone denote $(a,b)=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$.

Comment: @user31415 Not anyone in a peer-reviewed journal. But I wouldn't make that assumption about a random person on a website.

Answer (score 2):

If it has a root $\,b^2\equiv a\,$ then $\,0\equiv x^2\!-\!b^2\equiv (x\!-\!b)(x\!+\!b).\,$ Then prime $\,p\mid (x\!-\!b)(x\!+\!b)\,$ so $\,p\mid x\!-\!b\,$ or $\,x\!+\!b,\,$ so $\,x\equiv b\,$ or $\,-b,\,$ and $\,-b\not\equiv b,\,$ else $\, 2b\equiv 0,\,$ contra $\,(p,2)=1=(p,b^2)$

**Remark** $\ $ More generally a commutative ring $\ne 0$ is an integral domain $(a,b\ne 0\,\Rightarrow, ab\ne 0)$ iff nonzero polynomials over it have no more roots than their degree, as is easily shown via an inductive proof using the Factor Theorem, e.g. see the [BiFactor Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/868550/242)

Comment: @use It shows: if there is a solution $\,x\equiv b\,$ then there are exactly two solutions $\,x\equiv \pm b\pmod p.\ \ $