# Polynomial function

Tags: polynomials, factoring

When a polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by $x-5$ or $x-3$ or $x-2$ it leaves a remainder of $1$.  Which of the following would be the polynomial?

**a**. $ x^3 - 10x^2 + 31x + 31$

**b**.  $x^3 - 10x^2 + 31x - 31 $

**c**. $  x^3 - 10x^2 + 31x - 29$

**d**.  $x^3 - 10x^2 + 31x + 29$

Answer (score 5):

It would be
$$
(x-5)(x-3)(x-2)+1=x^3 - 10x^2 + 31x - 29.
$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:$$f\left( x \right)=\left( x-5 \right) \left( x-3 \right) \left( x-2 \right) +1$$

Comment: Could you explain how did you frame that equation as the question mentions that f(x) when divided by either of the three equation gives a remainder of 1

Comment: Because all $4$ possibilities had degree $3$. Of course, any polynomial $f(x)=g(x)(x-5)(x-3)(x-2)+1$ would satisfy the properties.

Comment: if polynomial function were so $\quad f\left( x \right) =\left( x-5 \right) \left( x-3 \right) \left( x-2 \right) $ then it would be divided to these three term,then what about reminder $1$

Comment: Thanks for making it easier to understand.

Comment: @Battani You have the same answer as this above.

Answer (score 3):

Set $f(x)=x^3+bx^2+cx+d$. we know $f(2)=f(3)=f(5)=1$. Hence
$$\left\{ \begin{align}
  & 4b+2c+d=-7 \\ 
 & 9b+3c+d=-26 \\ 
 & 25b+5c+d=-124 \\ 
\end{align} \right.$$
in other words
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
   4 & 2 & 1  \\
   9 & 3 & 1  \\
   25 & 5 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   b  \\
   c  \\
   d  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   -7  \\
   -26  \\
   -124  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
\\$$
By application of [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), we have
\begin{align}
  & b=\frac{\left| \begin{matrix}
   -7 & 2 & 1  \\
   -26 & 3 & 1  \\
   -124 & 5 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right|}{\left| \begin{matrix}
   4 & 2 & 1  \\
   9 & 3 & 1  \\
   25 & 5 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right|}=\frac{60}{-6}=-10 \\ 
\\
 & c=\frac{\left| \begin{matrix}
   4 & -7 & 1  \\
   9 & -26 & 1  \\
   25 & -124 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right|}{\left| \begin{matrix}
   4 & 2 & 1  \\
   9 & 3 & 1  \\
   25 & 5 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right|}=\frac{-183}{-6}=31 \\ 
\\
 & d=\frac{\left| \begin{matrix}
   4 & 2 & -7  \\
   9 & 3 & -26  \\
   25 & 5 & -124  \\
\end{matrix} \right|}{\left| \begin{matrix}
   4 & 2 & 1  \\
   9 & 3 & 1  \\
   25 & 5 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right|}=\frac{174}{-6}=-29 
\end{align}

Comment: What a lovely answer

Comment: @Behrouz i just want to know why you have assumed +bx^2 in the equation as the equation in the final answer has -10x^2

Comment: @Harry Harry Note $b=-10$ and $+bx^2=+(-10)x^2=-10x^2$

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki Battani's "hint" is simpler..

Answer (score 3):

Set $\;g(x)=x^3-10x^2+31x$. As the remainder upon division by $x-\alpha$ is $g(\alpha)$, it is enough to determine whether
$$g(5)=g(3)=g(2)= -30,\;32,\; 30\text{ or }-28, \;\text{ respectively}.$$
We'll check this with *Horner's scheme*:
$$\begin{array}{*{5}{r}}
&1&-10&3&0\\
\hline
&&5&-25&30\\
\hline
\times5&1&-5&6&\color{red}{30}\\
\hline\\\hline
&&3&-21&30\\
\hline
\times3&1&-7&10&\color{red}{30}\\
\hline\\\hline
&&2&-16&30\\
\hline
\times2&1&-8&15&\color{red}{30}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Thus $f(x)$ would be polynomial **c)**. Naturally, if we're confident such a polynomial exists in the list, one check will do.

Answer (score 2):

$x\!-\!2,x\!-\!3,x\!-\!5\mid f\!-\!1 \Rightarrow\, f = 1+(x\!-\!2)(x\!-\!3)(x\!-\!5)g.\,$ Comparing degree and lead coef shows $\,g = 1,\,$ therefore $\,f(0) = 1+(-2)(-3)(-5)=1-30 = -29,\,$ so it is choice $(c)$

Comment: **Remark** $ $ We iterated the Factor Theorem to deduce that the product of the $\,x-a_i\,$ divides $\,f\!-\!1,\,$ valid since the $\,a_i\,$ are *distinct*, e.g. see the [Bifactor Theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/868550/242) for the technique.