# divisibility in polynomial ring: if $(X - a)^t | f(X)$ and $(X - b)^t | f(X)$, then does $(X - a)^t \cdot (X - b)^t \mid f(X)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility, irreducible-polynomials, algebras

let $K$ be a field an $A$ a commutative $K$-algebra with unit. fix an element $f(X) \in A[X]$, unequal elements $a$ and $b$ of $K \subset A$, and an integer $t > 0$.

**Question.** if $(X - a)^t \mid f(X)$ and $(X - b)^t \mid f(X)$, then does $(X - a)^t \cdot (X - b)^t \mid f(X)$ in $A[X]$?

this is "trivial" when $A \mathbin{/} K$ is itself a field, essentially by unique factorization in $A[X]$: $X - a$ and $X - b$ are unequal irreducibles in this ring.

i can prove this in general in the case $t = 1$: in this case the hypothesis implies that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$. by the Euclidean algorithm, $f(X) = (X - a) \cdot q(X) + r(X)$, where $\deg(R) < 1$, and in fact $r = 0$ must hold. now $0 = f(b) = (b - a) \cdot q(b)$, so that $q(X)$ also vanishes at $b$ (here we use the fact that $b - a \in K \subset A$ is a unit), and so $q(X) = (X - b) \cdot q'(X)$ by the same logic. we see that $f(X) = (X - a) \cdot (X - b) \cdot q'(X)$, as desired.

what about $t > 1$?

Comment: Over $\Bbb Z_8$ we have $x\!-\!1,x\!-\!3\mid x^2\!-\!1=x^2\!-\!9\,$ but $\,(x\!-\!1)(x\!-\!3)\nmid x^2-1,\,$ see the [Bifactor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/868550/242). $\ \ $

Comment: indeed, the fact that $a$ and $b$ are in $K$ (and $b - a$ is a unit) will be essential if this is going to be true at all.

Comment: As explained in the answer I linked, we need $\,a-b\,$ is cancellable (not a zero-divisor). Does that post satisfy you as an answer to your question?

Comment: no; essentially the key problem here is that we need to handle $t > 1$ too. (my proof above of the case $t = 1$ is essentially the content of that post.)

Comment: $(x\!-\!a)^{k+1}\!\mid (x\!-\!a)^k(x\!-\!b)^tg\!\iff\! x\!-\!a\mid (x\!-\!b)^tg\!\iff\! (a\!-\!b)^tg(a)\!=\!0\!\iff\! g(a)\!=\!0\!\iff\! x\!-\!a\mid g\ \ $

Comment: i'm not sure i follow..... would you mind expanding this into an answer?

Comment: Let $\,h_k = (x\!-\!a)^k(x\!-\!b)^t.\,$ By above $\,h_k\mid f\Rightarrow h_{k+1}\mid f\,$ if $\,k<t.\,$ Base case $h_0\mid f$ is true by hypothesis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151856/discussion-between-bd107-and-bill-dubuque).

Comment: I appended the straightforward inductive extension to the linked [proof of the Bifactor Theorem,](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/868550/edit) so now the question is a dupe.