# $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=ab$ if and only if $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

I have a quick question about (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921109)'s answer. I asked on there but since the question is old, I feel like I might not get a reply. Anyway, my question was: Why is $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\leq drs$ like they said?

Comment: $drs$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$, right ?

Comment: There are many common multiples of $a$ and $b$.  For example, the common multiples of $6$ and $4$ are $\{12,24,36,48,60,72,\dots\}$.  The *least* common multiple is a common multiple, but more specifically it is *the* common multiple which is smaller than any other common multiple.

Comment: !!!!!!!!!! I really don't understand why out of all abstract algebra, I can never feel like I truly grasp LCM and GCD....thank you so much for the reminder...such an obvious reminder it is haha I wish I could give you both many many upvotes!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement it is assumed that *gcd(a,b)* = *d*, and *d > 1*. This means that the greatest common divisor between a and b is greater than 1, therefore they are not relatively prime (they share a factor, namely **d**).

Since we know that **d** divides both **a** and **b**, we can re-write **a** and **b** as

***a = d⋅r, b = d⋅s for some integers r and s.***

Considering our statement earlier, that **a** and **b** share a common factor **d**, we know that the least common multiple **[lcm(a,b)]** of **a** and **b** is some multiple of **d**, because both factors share a multiple **d**. The worst case scenario for the **lcm(a,b)** is going to be when **lcm(a,b) = d⋅r⋅s** because this will always be a factor of our two numbers **a** and **b** which share a common multiple.

Since we are talking about the LEAST common multiple, there can also be other common factors between them, but only if they are LESS than **d⋅r⋅s**. Hence the ***≤***.

We also know that since our **lcm(a,b)** is at most **d⋅r⋅s**, and **d > 1**, that **d⋅(d⋅r⋅s)** should surely be greater than **d⋅r⋅s**. Therefore **lcm(a,b) ≤ d⋅r⋅s < d⋅(d⋅r⋅s)** which we know is equal to ***a⋅b***