# Proof that if gcd(a, b) = 1, then lcm(a, b) = ab

Tags: solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to show the following. If $gcd(a,b) = 1$ then $lcm(a, b)=ab$. I am assuming a and b are positive integers.

I have looked at the following questions on here which are using different presumed theorems that I don't have.

[first link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2817709/if-gcda-b-1-then-operatornamelcma-b-ab#:%7E:text=Since%20gcd(a%2Cb))

[second link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920978/show-that-lcma-b-ab-if-and-only-if-gcda-b-1/921109#921109)

But both assume the notion of prime factorisation. I am working out the exercises in the appendix of Pinters - "A book of abstract algebra" before starting the book proper. I only have the following to work with:
Bezouts lemma, definitions of gcd, lcm, relatively prime integers and definition of division, multiples etc.

My attempt to prove it is as follows:
Proof: Assume $a$ and $b$ are integers and $gcd(a,b)=1$. Then $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and it follows that there exists integers $k$ and $l$ such that $1 = ak + bl$. Let $m$ be a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. Then $m=ar$ and $m=bs$ for some integers $r$ and $s$. Multiplying $1=ak+bl$ through by m we have: 
$m = akm +blm = ak(bs) + bl(ar) = (ab)(ks + lr)$. As $ks + lr$ is an integer $ab|m$. Clearly $a|ab=m$ and $b|ab=m$

Hence $a|ab$, $b|ab$ and for any multiple of $a$ and $b$, $m$, $ab|m$ hence $ab=lcm(a,b)$ $\square$

Any corrections are welcome. 
Again, as I said before I have limited definitions and theorems to work with so I have to stick to basic approaches.

If I were to try to prove this for $a$, $b$ negative or positive how would I proceed? would I need to do four cases to prove it for the various cases where $a$ and $b$ are positive and negative?

Comment: Looks fine to me!

Comment: That common Bezout-based proof already occurs in many prior answers, e.g. see the linked dupes.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: Your proof is correct, and is as basic as it gets I would say. Notice that you didn't use positivity of $a$ or $b$ in your argument, which means that it's still valid if you were to consider negative integers. Since $\text{gcd}$ and $\text{lcm}$ are defined as positive integers, in the case that just one of the integers $a$ or $b$ is negative, you would need to tweak some signs so that $-ab = \text{lcm}(a,b).$