# Modular exponentiation using Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

> Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct odd primes and write $$n=\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{2}$$ Show that $$x^n\equiv 1\mod pq$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $\gcd(x,pq)=1$.

I tried solving it the following way. Since $$\varphi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)=2n$$ (where $\varphi$ denotes Euler's totient function), we have, by Euler's congruence, that $$x^{\varphi(n)}=x^{2n}\equiv 1\mod pq$$ whenever $\gcd(x,pq)=1$. However, I don't see how I can reduce the power of $x$ from $2n$ to $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** You know $(x^n)^2-1\equiv (x^n+1)(x^n-1)\equiv 0$. This means that both $p$ and $q$ divide $(x^n+1)(x^n-1)$. Show that neither $p$ nor $q$ divides $x^n+1$.

---

Actually, the previous argument is unduly complicated. Since Fermat's little theorem implies $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$, you have
$$
x^n=(x^{p-1})^{(q-1)/2}\equiv 1^{(q-1)/2}=1\pmod p.
$$
This means $p$ divides $x^n-1$. By the same logic, $q$ divides $x^n-1$, so $pq$ divides $x^n-1$.

Comment: Worth emphasis: the 2nd proof is essentially the special case $\,c = 2\,$ in $\,c\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid ab/c\,$ as I explain in the remark in my answer. $\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ 2\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow a,b\mid ab/2\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{{\rm lcm}(a,b)}\mid \color{#0a0}{ab/2}$

[Recall:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3859811/242)  $\ \ \ \begin{align} x^{\large a}\equiv 1\!\!\!\pmod{\!p}\\ x^{\large b}\equiv 1\!\!\!\pmod{\!q}\end{align}\,\Rightarrow\, x^{\large \color{#c00}{{\rm lcm}(a,b)}}\equiv 1\pmod{\!pq},\, $ so $\ x^{\large\color{#0a0}{ab/2}}\equiv 1\pmod{\!pq}\ $ by above

**Remark** $ $ It stays true if we replace $\,2\,$ by any conmon divisor $\,c\mid a,b.\,$ Thus we can cancel $c$ from the "obvious" common multiple $\,ab\,$ to obtain a smaller one $\,m = ab/c.\ $  $\,c\,$ is *greatest* $\iff m\,$ is *least*, which leads to a [duality based proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921108/242) of $\:{\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab/\gcd(a,b)$

Answer (score 0):

As you (the OP) pointed out, $x^{\varphi(n)}=x^{2n}\equiv 1\mod pq$, whenever $\gcd(x,pq)=1$. So the question is, does this imply $x^{n}\equiv 1\mod pq$ whenever $\gcd(x,pq)=1$?

If this were false, there would be $y\neq 1$ so that $y^2\equiv1$ mod $pq$, what this would mean that $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ would have an element of order 2 (namely $y$). But all of it's elements are of order $p,q$ or $pq$(By Lagrange theorem)

Comment: In $\mathbb Z_{3\cdot 5}$, $4\not\equiv 1$, yet $4^2\equiv1$. Since you are talking about multiplicative orders, the group of interest is $\mathbb Z_{pq}^\times$, which has order $(p-1)(q-1)$, which does have $2$ as a factor.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Ooooh, how could I miss that? You're right of course