# Prove that if $\gcd(a,480)=1$, then $a^{16} ≡ 1 \pmod{480}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I would like to prove it using Euler's Theorem, which states that if $\gcd(a,n)=1$,then $a^{\phi(n)}=1 \pmod{n}$. Then, $480$ should be factored, but I am unsure how to proceed with the proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you at least calculate $\phi(480)$?

Comment: Yes! $\phi(480)=128$, but I do not understand how that helps.

Comment: @qt_314, s use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

Comment: Same proofs as in the dupe work here.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you so much! I apologize for posting a duplicate question.

Comment: It's best for site health to delete dupes of FAQs (we have many tens if not hundreds of posts on this topic - little new can be said). The dupes make it harder to locate the best answers when searching (which you should always do before asking a question).

Comment: @BillDubuque I will certainly delete it then. First, if you don't mind me asking, what did you search to find the duplicate?

Comment: I used keywords like Euler. phi, carmichael but you could also search on equations using https://approach0.xyz/search/

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks again. Just tried to delete the post, but it said I cannot since others have already answered it. Is there something else I should do? Sorry, I am new to this site.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $480 = 2^5 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$. By the Chinese remainder theorem, we see that $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod {480}$ if and only if we have
$$
\begin{cases}
a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{2^5},\\
a^k \equiv 1 \pmod 3,\\
a^k \equiv 1 \pmod 5.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain how this relates to Euler's Theorem?

Comment: @qt_314 The approach I suggest to this problem does not involve Euler's theorem at all, if that's what you mean. When I made my earlier comment, I had not yet thought of this approach.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @qt_314 See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3859811/242) for motivation on the relationship between little Fermat and Euler.