# Why it looks like divisor is more important than multiple?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, soft-question

So far as I've been reading any number theory and algebra books,

They seem to take more care of **"divisor"** than of **"multiple"**.

But I haven't seen any kind of number theory beginning with "multiple".

I guess one of the reasons is that multiples are easy to be calculated, you just multiply.
(Of course, it takes a little bit of time.)

But divisors are not easy, if you give me tremendously big number, say $10^{100}$-digit number and ask me to find its divisors, I couldn't do that even if I'm allowed to use my calculator.

I guess there is a huge gap between their complexity of computations.

I'd like to know whether there is any reason why they start with divisors.

Comment: It's exactly that. The problem of finding all multiples of $n$ is trivial: we just have $\{mn:m\in\Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: There are some topics involving "multiple," such as "least common multiple."

Comment: @ElliotG It's not necessarily trivial, e.g. the involution (reflection) $\, n\mapsto ab/n\,$ gives an $\rm\color{#c00}{order\ reversing}$ bijection of common divisors of $\,a,b\,$ with common multiples of $a,b$ (below $ab),\,$ so it maps the $\rm\color{#c00}{greatest}$ common divisor to the $\rm\color{#c00}{least}$ common multiple [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921108/242) $\,{\rm lcm}(a,b)= ab/\gcd(a,b).\,$ Follow the link for more on such duality.