# Prove that $lcm(a,b)=ab$ iff a,b are relatively prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Since this is an iff proof, I know it needs to be proved both ways, but I can't figure out the other way. Can someone look over what I have so far and see if it makes sense and help me out going the other way?

Proof

$<==$ If a and b are relatively prime, by definition, then $gcd(a,b)=1$.

We can also. use the. fact that $gcd(a,b)*lcm(a,b)= ab$
Now plugging in $gcd(a,b)=1$ we get:

$$1*lcm(a,b)=ab$$
$$lcm(a,b)=ab$$, just like we wanted.

$==>$ help?

Comment: If you know that $\gcd(a,b)\times \text {lcm(a,b)}=ab$  then...isn't it clear?  If $A\times B=C$ for positive numbers $A,B,C$ then $B=C\iff A=1$.

Comment: Simply rewrite your resoning whith equivalences instead of implications.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that lcm$(a,b)= ab$ if and only if gcd$(a,b)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920978/show-that-lcma-b-ab-if-and-only-if-gcda-b-1) - found as the referenced question in Anne's proposed duplicate of [$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=ab$ if and only if $\gcd(a,b)=1$](/q/2817677).