# How Lagrange Interpolation works by Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Find the polynomial of $2$nd degree such that

a. $p(1)=0,p(2)=0,p(3)=4$

b.$p(1)=0,p(2)=2,p(3)=0$

c. $p(1)=6,p(2)=0,p(3)=0$ and

d. $p(1)=6,p(2)=2,p(3)=4$.

The solutions for $a,b,c$ are straightforward. For (d) it was given that the sum of three preceding solutions gives the desired polynomial.It is not obvious to me why such is the case.

Comment: For the future, putting dollar signs ($) around your math equations will make the render nicely.

Comment: And if you want to have a newline appear in the question, you have to skip two lines when you type it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise is most likely intended to motivate [Lagrange interpolation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) Here is the basic idea. Let $\,\Bbb P_2\,$ be the polynomials of degree at most $2$. Consider the evaluation map $\,E\,:\ \Bbb P_2\to \Bbb R^3\,$ such that $\, E(p(x)) = [p(1),p(2),p(3)].\,$ Construct basis polynomials $\,p_1,p_2,p_3\,$ such that

$$\begin{array}{rll} p_1 =\ \frac{1}2\!\!\!\!\!&(x-2)(x-3)\overset{E}\longrightarrow  [1,0,0]\\
\\
p_2 =\ &\!\!\!\!\!-(x-1)(x-3)\overset{E}\longrightarrow [0,1,0]\\
\\
p_2 =\ \frac{1}2\!\!\!\!\!&(x-1)(x-2)\overset{E}\longrightarrow  [0,0,1]\end{array}\qquad$$

Note $\,E\,$ is $\,\Bbb R$-linear, i.e. $\,E(r p + s q) = r E(p) + s E(q)\,$ for $\,r,s\in\Bbb R,\,$ therefore

$$ E(r_1 p_1 + r_2 p_2 + r_3 p_3)\, =\, r_1[1,0,0]+r_2[0,1,0]+r_3[0,0,1] \,=\,[r_1,r_2,r_3]$$

Thus $\,E\,$ is surjective. This yields the *existence* of a solution to the problem of interpolating a quadratic polynomial $\,p(x)\,$ with values $\,r_1,r_2,r_3\,$ at $\,x = 1,2,3.$

Also $\,E\,$ is injective, which yields the *uniqueness* of the interpolating polynomial. Indeed,  $\,E(p)=E(q)\,\Rightarrow [0,0,0] = E(p)-E(q) = E(p-q).\,$ [Therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37519/242) $\,p-q = 0,\,$ being a quadratic with $3$ roots $\,x=1,2,3,\,$ i.e. more roots than its degree.

**Remark** $\ $ The same idea works generally for $\,i=1,\ldots,n.\,$ We seek $\,p_i(x)\,$ ith $\,p_i(i) =1\,$ and $\,p_i(j) = 0\,$ if $\,j\neq i.\,$ Thus all $\,x-j\,$ divide $\,p_i\,$ except  $\,\color{#c00}{x-i}.\,$ Therefore we can write $\,p_i\,$ as follows, where the $\,\rm\color{#c00}{red}$ term is omitted $$\require{cancel}\,p_i(x)\, =\, c_i(x\!-\!1)(x\!-\!2)\cdots\color{#c00}{\cancel{(x-i)}}\cdots (x-n)\,$$
Finally, from $\,p_i(i) = 1\,$ we can evaluate the above at $\,x=i\,$ to solve for $\,c_i.\,$

If you know some linear algebra then you may find it helpful to express the above more precisely in that language (I avoided that in case it is not known). If you know the ring-theoretic Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) then you can view such Lagrange interpolation as a special case of applying CRT to the system

$$\begin{align}
p(x) \equiv r_1 \pmod{x-1}\\
p(x) \equiv r_2 \pmod{x-2}\\
p(x) \equiv r_3 \pmod{x-3} \end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: That was way too advanced for me to comprehend. I shall refer back to it after i learn  higher mathematics . Thank  you. :)

Comment: @Aditya The part before the remark is at the level of Gelfand's book (it can be explained at high-school level). If you let me know what is not clear then I can elaborate.

Comment: I am a self learner going through Gelfand's book. I am not yet familiar with the notation in your answer.

Comment: @Aditya I'll be happy to explain it if you are interested.

Comment: Please do. A couple of other problems  i am working on apparently lead to lagrange interpolation.

Comment: Please tell me more precisely what notation etc. is unfamiliar.

Comment: I have looked up the explicit statement of lagrange interpolation which agrees with my own findings. However can i "construct" the polynomials whose sum gives P(x).{How do i state it in the actual proof}

Comment: @Aditya I added more to the remark. The same idea works for arbitrary points $\,a_i\,$ vs. $\,a_i = 1,\ldots,n.\ $

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_a(x)$ be the polynomial that satisfies the conditions in $a$, and similarly for $p_b(x)$ and $p_c(x)$. You are looking now for $p_d(x)$.

The book is pointing out that $p_d(1) = p_a(1)+p_b(1)+p_c(1)$.

So too is $p_d(2) = p_a(2)+p_b(2)+p_c(2)$, and similarly for $p_d(3)$.

So $p_a(x)+p_b(x)+p_c(x)$ meets the conditions of $d$, and you can conclude $p_d(x)=p_a(x)+p_b(x)+p_c(x)$.

Comment: I just realized that there was a proof in the book that any polynomial of nth degree is uniquely defined by n+1 values (3 in this case). Thanks. ;)