# Any reference for citation for the following theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, reference-request

I am searching for some reference book for the following theorem in polynomials for citation. Could anybody provide me some details?

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $p$ be a prime, and let $\{(x_1,y_1), \ldots ,(x_{t+1},y_{t+1})\}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ to be a set of points whose $x_i$ values are all distinct. Then there is a unique degree-$t$ polynomial $f$ with coefficients from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ that satisfies $y_i \equiv_p f(x_i)$ for all $i$ (I would add to the theorem where $s=f(0)$).

P.S. Is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ notation the same with $GF(p)$?

Comment: $GF(p)$ is the galois-field with $p$ elements, so the same as $\mathbb Z_p$. In a field we have the property that a poylnomial with degree $n$ can have at most $n$ roots, hence the uniqueness follows easily. For the existence, you can use the Newton-approach or the Lagrange-interpolating-polynomial. Both lead to the unique polynomial doing the job.

Comment: A reference, among others, is the number theory book by Ireland and Rosen.

Comment: this one https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2103-4 ?

Comment: Since [Lagrange interpolation is a special case of CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a242%20%20crt%20interpolation) it suffices to cite a general proof of CRT, e.g. see see Prop. 1.10 in Atiyah & MacDonald's *Intro to Commutative Algebra*.

Comment: @BillDubuque you mean that prop $1.10$ from the book is equivalent to the theorem above?

Comment: Not equivalent, rather such interpolation is a special case of CRT, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3556444/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2383905/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1208390/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque sorry but I do not get the similarities....sorry...it is my problem...but I don't get it...I mean the similarities from the book you propose with the theorem above...

Comment: I edited [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3556444/242) to show how the CRT formula specializes to the Lagrange interpolation formula.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks anyway!You are very helpful and your answers are very informative.

Comment: As you write it it makes no sense, because the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (equivalently, $\mathbb{F}_p$) are not ordered pairs. The set should be contained in $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: One should be careful with "$\mathbb{Z}_p$", and the notation may mean "the integers modulo $p$" (which in this case is the same as the field with $p$ elements, $GF(p)$ or $\mathbb{F}_p$), but could also mean "the $p$-adic integers". In this case, it plainly means "the integers modulo $p$", but one must be careful and explicit.