# Polynomial equal to polynomial of lower degree

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I am studying Linear Algebra Done Right, chapter 2 problem 6 states:

> Prove that the real vector space consisting of all continuous real valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ is infinite dimensional.

**My solution:**

Consider the sequence of functions $x, x^2, x^3, \dots$ 
This is a linearly independent infinite sequence of functions so clearly this space cannot have a finite basis.
However this prove relies on the fact that no $x^n$ is a linear combination of the previous terms. In other words, is it possible for a polynomial of degree $n$ to be equal to a polynomial of degree less than $n$. I believe this is not possible, but does anyone know how to prove this? More specifically, could the following equation ever be true for all $x$?

$x^n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} a_kx^k$ where each $a_k \in \mathbb R$

Answer (score 12):

Then the polynomial $\displaystyle x^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kx^k$ would have infinitely many roots, but it can have $n$, at most.

---

Another way of dealing with this problem is based upon *defining* polynomials (in one variable $x$) as expressions of the type $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n$, where $n\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ and each $a_n$ is real. Under this definition, the polynomial $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n$ is equal to the polynomial $b_0+b_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+b_nx^n$ if and only if the coefficients are equal, that is, if and only if $a_0=b_0$, $a_1=b_1$, and so on. Under this definition, the problem discussed here is trivial.

What did I prove above then? Well, for each $P(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, there is a corresponding *polynomial function* from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$. What I proved above is that this correspondence is one-to-one — when we are dealing with $\mathbb R$. It is still one-to-one if we are dealing with any field with charactristic $0$, such as $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb C$. But this is *not* true in general. For instance, if our field is $\mathbb{F}_2$, then $x$ and $x^2$ are distinct polynomials. But they correspond to the *same* polynomial function.

Comment: "Equations" can have infinitely many solutions, but *nonzero polynomials* cannot.

Comment: Thank you I just need to find a proof of that fact. If you have any good references that would be great.

Comment: @Joe A reference? Why? Isn't my proof clear?

Comment: @Joe See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) for a proof of the root bound for polynomials.

Comment: A proof of the fact that a polynomial of degree n has at most n solutions.

Comment: @BillDubuque I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Joe You can find several proofs of the [Fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

Comment: @Joe See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25822/how-to-prove-that-a-polynomial-of-degree-n-has-at-most-n-roots).

Comment: @BillDubuque I think you mean "a proof for the root bound for *nonzero* polynomials" :P

Comment: @Joe If you know about unique factorization of polynomials over fields then a [slick proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37519/242) is that if a nonzero polynomial has infinitely many roots $r_i$ then it has infinitely many nonassociate prime factors $\,x - r_i,\,$ contra unique factorization.

Comment: In Linear Algebra Done Right, Sheldon Axler states on page 24 that the fact that a polynomial of degree m has at most m roots will be proved in chapter 4. I think maybe I should just wait until chapter 4. Are there other ways to prove the original question without this fact about polynomials?

Comment: @Joe Please read my expanded answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But it seems like you are going around the problem by changing the definition of a polynomial?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Jokes aside, I really do mean what I wrote. We should expect *statements* of results to be precise, but not *names* of results (else we'd be stuck with monstrous names like "the root bound for nonzero formal univariate polynomials over a commutative integral domain").

Comment: @BillDubuque That makes sense! I hadn't thought about that distinction before.

Comment: @Joe I just wanted to make you aware of the distinction between *polynomial* and *polynomial function*. Perhaps that Axler assumed that his readers knew that a poynomial with degree $n$ has, at most, $n$ roots. Or perhaps that he had in mind a solution without poynomials. For instance, he might have been thinking about functions of the type $f_n(x)=(x-n)(1-x+n)$, which are zero outside the interval $(n,n+1)$ and non-zero inside. Therefore, they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 6):

By definition, $x^n + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k x^k$ is a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$.  A nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ zeros in any field, and $[0,1]$ has more than $n$ elements.

Answer (score 5):

Two identical functions have identical derivatives. Differentiate your equality $n$ times and you will see the two sides cannot be identical.

Comment: Good point, but I have not studied derivatives on a rigorous level yet... so I can't really use that as part of my proof.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x^n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} a_kx^k$. Consider what happens when $x$ is much larger than  $|a_1|+\ldots+|a_{n-1}|$. By the triangle inequality, you will get a contradiction. Essentially, you are showing that $x^n$ grows faster than any degree $n-1$ polynomial...