# Confused on Proof that Polynomials of Degree $n$ has at most $n$ zeroes (counting multiplicity) from Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

I am a bit confused on the proof that Gallian delivers of the theorem mentioned in the title. Although I have seen other proofs of this fact and have been able to parse them, his specifically trips me up as I cannot understand the purpose of a lot of it. Word for word:

**A polynomial of degree $n$ over a field has at most $n$ zeros, counting multiplicity.**

> **Proof:** We proceed by induction on $n$. Clearly, a polynomial of degree $0$ over a field has no zeros. Now suppose that $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ over a field and $a$ is a zero of $f(x)$ of multiplicity $k$. Then, $f(x) = (x-a)^kq(x)$ and $q(a) \ne 0$; and, since $n = \text{deg} f(x) = \text{deg} (x-a)^kq(x) = k + \text{deg} q(x)$, we have $k \le  n$ (see Exercise 19) If $f(x)$ has no zeros other than $a$, we are done. On the other hand, if $b \ne a$ and $b$ is a zero of $f(x)$ then $0 = f(b) = (b-a)^k q(b)$ so that $b$ is also a zero of $q(x)$ with the same multiplicity as it has for $f(x)$ (see Exercise 21). By the Second Principle of Mathematical Induction, we know that $q(x)$ has at most deg$q(x) = n-k$ zeros, counting multiplicity. Thus $f(x)$ has at most $k + n - k = n$ zeros, counting multiplicity.

I'm wondering why couldn't of it been possible to say something along the lines of:

**Proof** Assuming that the theorem is true for a polynomial of degree $n$, we show that it is true for a polynomial $f_{n+1}$ of degree $n+1$. The base case of a degree $0$ polynomial is trivial.

Let $f_{n+1}$ have a zero $a$ of multiplicity $k \ge 1$. Then we know that

$$f_{n+1} = (x-a)^k q(x)$$

Since there are no zero divisors in a field, we know that the 'degree rule' holds: that is $\text{deg} (f(x)g(x)) = \text{deg} f(x) + \text{deg} g(x)$. And so we know that $\text{deg}  q(x) = n+1-k$. Since $q(x)$ has degree $\le n$, we can utilize our induction hypothesis and come to the conclusion that $q(x)$ has at most $n + 1 - k$ zeros. And so, $f_{n+1}$ has at most $n + 1 - k + (k) = n + 1$ zeros, and the theorem is proven. $\blacksquare$

This doesn't utilize any information that wasn't used in Gallian's proof - proving the "Degree Rule" was what "Exercise 19" was. I both don't really *understand* or *see why* the whole second part of Gallian's proof introducing $b$ is necessary. On top of that, it's kind of hard to understand.

I was hoping if someone could help me in both explaining why my proof is incorrect (if it is) and how the second half of Gallian's proof operates.

Thank you!

Comment: @PaulFrost, you are right!!! Thanks for reminding that. I will delete the comment

Comment: The proof can be viewed [more *conceptually*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37519/242) as  $\,(x\!-\!a_1)^{e_1},\ldots, (x-a_j)^{e_j}\!\mid f\Rightarrow \prod_i (x\!-\!a_i)^{e_i}\mid f\,$ because LCM = product for pair-coprimes, where the inductive step amounts to *Euclid's Lemma* (the key point your argument omits).  If this interests you then let me know and I can explain further in an answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque Bill, that would actually be wonderful - I'm still having a bit of trouble understanding the connections between the theorem and Euclid's Lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have used the same proof as you suggested, but I realized that it has a little gap: We have to show that all zeros of $f(x)$ are zeros of one of its factors. This seems to be trivial; nevertheless it deserves a proof. The sentence

> On the other hand, if $b \ne a$ and $b$ is a zero of $f(x)$ then $0 = f(b) = (b-a)^k q(b)$ so that $b$ is also a zero of $q(x)$ with the same multiplicity as it has for $f(x)$

gives a proof of this fact.

Comment: The proof is a special case of the standard proof that  LCM = product for coprimes, and that sentence (inductive step) is merely an application of Euclid's Lemma (cf. my comment on the answer).