# How do we solve quadratic congruences such as $X^2+ 3X \equiv -5 \mod{7}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do we solve quadratic congruences such as:
$$
X^2+ 3X \equiv -5 \mod{7}
$$

Comment: Well, for such a small modulus we can just try everything. For larger moduli, we can use a variant of the familiar quadratic formula. We will need to solve congruences of the shape $Y^2\equiv a \pmod{p}$, for which there are good algorithms.

Comment: Hmm. Is this a duplicate of for example [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/44773/11619)? (probably better older matches exist)

Answer (score 2):

As $(2,7)=1,$ $$x^2+3x\equiv-5\pmod7\iff4x^2+12x+20\equiv0\pmod7$$

$$(2x+3)^2\equiv-11\equiv3\pmod7$$

But $a\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\pmod7\implies a^2\equiv0,1,4,2\pmod7$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
**I.** The equation is equivalent with $(x+5)^2\equiv-1\pmod7.$
**II.** $x^2\equiv-1\pmod7$ jas no solutions by the [supplemented reciprocity law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.E2.88.921_and_the_first_supplement).
Hope this helps.