# Possible division by zero when repeatedly factoring and canceling (x-r) and evaluating the resulting polynomial at x=r...

Tags: polynomials, partial-fractions

The following proof is from '[Two Proofs of the Existence and Uniqueness of the Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf/imf-2012/29-32-2012/cookIMF29-32-2012.pdf)', page 4.

---

**Lemma 2.1.** Let $h(x), g(x) \in R[x]$ (real polynomials), $k$ a positive integer, and $r \in \mathbb R$ such that $g(r) \neq 0$. If $A_1,...,A_k \in \mathbb R$ such that $h(x)(x-r)^k+A_1g(x)(x-r)^{k-1}+A_2g(x)(x-r)^{k-2}+$
$...+A_kg(x)=0$, then $A_1=A_2=...=A_k=0$.

**Proof:** If we evaluate $h(x)(x-r)^k+A_1g(x)(x-r)^{k-1}+A_2g(x)(x-r)^{k-2}+...+A_kg(x)=0$ at $x=r$, we get $h(x)(0)^k+A_1g(x)(0)^{k-1}+A_2g(x)(0)^{k-2}+...+A_kg(x)=0$. So that $A_kg(r)=0$. However, $g(r) \neq 0$ therefore, $A_k=0$.

Now our equation reads $h(x)(x-r)^k+A_1g(x)(x-r)^{k-1}+...+A_{k-1}g(x)(x-r)=0$. Factoring out and canceling $x-r$, gives us $h(x)(x-r)^{k-1}+A_1g(x)(x-r)^{k-2}+...+A_{k-1}g(x)$
$=0$.

Therefore, applying the same argument again we find that $A_{k-1}=0$. Continuing in this fashion we find that $A_1=A_2=...=A_k=0$.

---

My question is whether it is legal to repeatedly factor and cancel $(x-r)$ and at each step evaluate the resulting polynomial at $x=r$. Doesn't the domain of the resulting polynomial exclude $x = r$?

Alternatively I have looked at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60261/polynomial-px-0-for-all-x-implies-coefficients-of-polynomial-are-zero) for a different proof but I am not sure how to apply the given answers to prove the above lemma.

Comment: Yes, the factoring and cancellations are legal since they are polynomials. The domain of a polynomial is always $\mathbb{R}$. So you can evaluate it at any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's legal: if $k=1$ you are finished. If $k>1$, after the first step you find that
$$
h(x)(x-r)^k+A_1g(x)(x-r)^{k-1}+\dots+A_{k-1}g(x)(x-r)=
(x-r)\bigl(h(x)(x-r)^{k-1}+A_1g(x)(x-r)^{k-2}+\dots+A_{k-1}g(x)\bigr)
$$
is the zero polynomial. Since $x-r$ is not the zero polynomial, we conclude that
$$
h(x)(x-r)^{k-1}+A_1g(x)(x-r)^{k-2}+\dots+A_{k-1}g(x)=0
$$
If you still doubt it, take derivatives:
$$
h'(x)(x-r)^k+kh(x)(x-r)^{k-1}+
A_1g'(x)(x-r)^{k-1}+(k-1)A_1g(x)(x-r)^{k-2}+\dots+
A_{k-1}g'(x)(x-r)+A_{k-1}g(x)=0
$$
and evaluating at $r$ gives $A_{k-1}g(r)=0$, so $A_{k-1}=0$.

Then you can go on in the same way.