# Polynomial on Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume for any $t \in \mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{C}$ denotes set of complex numbers, we have

$P(t) = 1$, where $P$ is a polynomial.

Does it imply that for any matrix $A$, $P(A)=I$?

Comment: I think it should be true since for any matrix, its eigenvalue is a root of the polynomial $P(t)-1$, so it should be possible to conclude that the matrix itself is a root of $P(A)-I$? I am not sure tough.

Comment: Could you give an example of a non-constant polynomial that satisfies this condition?

Comment: I meant something like $(t+1)(t-1)- t^2$, but you are right it is a constant polynomial. I did not see this the first time.

Comment: We can use the *fundamental theorem of algebra* to prove that there only exist exactly **one** polynomial($p(x)$) which is equal to $1$ for all $x$. (Hint: Assume the degree is $n$ and you can have $n+1$ roots and hence an identity.) And the only polynomial is $p(x)=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a polynomial as you describe, it must hold that the polynomial is $P(t)=1$ (the only polynomial function over the complex numbers that always evaluates to $1$ is the constant polynomial $P(t)=1$). So, of course it holds that $P(A)=I$, by definition of evaluating polynomials on matrices.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ A nonzero polynomial with coefficients over a [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) or [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) (e.g. $\,\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q,\Bbb C)\,$ has no more roots that its degree. Therefore, if $\:P(t)-1\:$ has infinitely many roots, then it must be the constant zero polynomial, hence $\:P(t)\:$ is the constant polynomial $\,1$.

**Remark** $\ $ This may fail over more general coefficient rings, e.g. $\,t^2\!-1\,$ has *four* roots $\,t = \pm1,\,\pm3\,$ over $\,\Bbb Z/3 = $ integers mod $3.\:$ For proofs and various viewpoints of this fundamental theorem about polynomials see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/111309/23500) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113430/23500) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93537/23500) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/173483/23500)