# Reduced multiplicative residue modulo p

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I would like if someone could provide or show me where I can find the proof that $\mathbb{Z} _n^*$ is cyclic when n is prime. In particular I'm after a simple proof that involves fermats little theorem. Would appreciate it best regards.

Comment: Not a duplicate as I'm looking for a specific and less general result. In particular trying to avoid theory I do not know.

Comment: Well, at some point you'll need to use the fact that, $\pmod p$, a non-zero polynomial of degree $d$ can have no more than $d$ roots.  That follows instantly from the fact that the integers, $\pmod p$ form a field.  I don't think you'll find a short cut round that fact.

Comment: @lulu "instantly" is a bit of a stretch (at this level), but it does follow easily by inductively applying the Factor Theoem e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242), or by [using](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93537/242) $\,x-a\,$ is prime over a domain. $\ \ $