# Ring and Subring have different identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a commutative ring with identity 1 and $(S,+,\cdot)$ is a subring with identity 1'. Prove that if $1\ne 1'$, then 1' is a zero divisor in $(R,+,\cdot)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Let $e$ be the identity of the subring. Look at $(1-e)e$.

Comment: umm.. I found the ring R has zero divisors! But I don't know 1' that is subring's identity is zero divisor of R....

Comment: @J.G.Lee -- if you compute the value $(1-e)e$ you will have constructed a proof that the identity of the subring is a zero divisor.

Comment: @Nick Thanks!! I'm so stupid;;

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ The *quadratic* $\,x^2 = x\,$ has *three* solutions $\,0,1,1'$ [hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113430/242) the difference of some pair of roots must be a zero divisor. Indeed, evaluate $\,x(x-1)=0\,$ at $\,x=1'.$