# If $A$ is an integral domain and $a^2=1$, then $a=1$ or $a=-1$

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain

I have looked at the definition of an integral domain and tried multiple equivalencies of being an integral domain but still can't figure out how to prove that:

**Proposition:** If $A$ is an integral domain and $a^2=1$, then $a=1$ or $a=-1$.

I would appreciate any clues on how to start this proof.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112677/proving-that-an-integral-domain-has-at-most-two-elements-that-satisfy-the-equati

Answer (score 3):

If $a^2=1$, then $a^2-1=0$. Factor the left hand side, and use the fact that there are no zero divisors.