# Characterization of all those integral domain for which $1$ is the only element that is its own multiplicative inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

For any element $x$ which is self invertible, we have $x^{2}=1$. And
$(x-1)(x+1)=0$ which implies $x$ must be either $1$ or $-1$ as we have considered an integral domain.

---

I was wondering whether there are more such elements or these are the only ones? With the help of the above, can we characterize all those integral domain for which $1$ is the only element that is its own multiplicative inverse?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "more such elements"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that an integral domain has at most two elements that satisfy the equation $x^2 = 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112677/proving-that-an-integral-domain-has-at-most-two-elements-that-satisfy-the-equati)

Comment: Actually I was trying to characterize all those integral domains for which $1$ is the only element that is its own multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @curious_soul Trivially, yes. It would necessitate that $1=-1$, that is, the domain has characteristic $2$. Then you have your characterization: domains with characteristic 2.

Comment: @rschwieb thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are no more such elements and your proof is sufficient.