# Multiplicative Selfinverse in Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I assume there are only two multiplicative self inverse in each field with characteristice bigger than $2$ (the field is finite but I think it holds in general). In a field $F$ with $\operatorname{char}(F)>2$ a multiplicative self inverse $a \in F$ is an element such that

$$ a \cdot a = 1.$$

I think in each field it is $1$ and $-1$. Any ideas how to proof that?

Comment: This doesn't hold in characteristic 2, only 1 will be a self inverse in that case (note 1=-1).

Comment: Is 1=-1 for every field with characteristic 2?

Comment: @joachim: Yes, because a field $F$ has characteristic 2 precisely when $1_F+1_F=0_F$, where $0_F$ and $1_F$ are the additive and multiplicative identities of $F$, respectively. Thus $1_F=-1_F$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equation $x^2-1$ is degree $2$ and thus can have at most two solutions in any field. So checking that $1$ and $-1$ satisfy this is enough to know that they are the only self-inverse elements. (As Nate points out, in the field of characteristic $2$ they are also equal to each other, so there is only one self-inverse element in this case).

Comment: Since $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$, you don't even need to worry about polynomials: $(x-1)(x+1)=0$ in a field implies that one factor is 0.... This proof actually works in an integral domain....

Comment: Also, might be worth pointing, that outside integral domains this is not true: in M_2 the diagonal matrix $A$ with 1 and -1 on the diagonal satisfies this relation, and so does any matrix of the form $PAP^{-1}$. It is easy to show that there are infinitely many such matrices....

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\ x^2\! =\! 1\!\iff\! (x\!-\!1)(x\!+\!1) = 0\! \iff\! x = \pm1,\:$ by $\rm\:ab=0\:\Rightarrow\: a=0\:\ or\:\ b=0\:$ in a field.

This may fail if the latter property fails, i.e. if nontrivial zero-divisors exist. Consider, for example,  $\rm\ x^2 = 1\:$ has $4$ roots $\rm\:x = \pm1, \pm 3\:$ in $\rm\:\mathbb Z/8 = $ integers mod $8,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:odd^2 \equiv 1\pmod 8$.

Rings satsifying the latter property (no zero-divisors) are called (integral) *domains.* They are characterized by a generalization of the above, viz. a ring $\rm\: D\:$ is a domain $\iff$ every nonzero polynomial $\rm\ f(x)\in D[x]\ $ has at most $\rm\ deg\ f\ $ roots in $\rm\:D.\:$ For the simple proof see my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/simple-explanation-and-examples-of-the-miller-rabin-primality-test/4604#4604), where I illustrate it constructively in $\rm\: \mathbb Z/m\: $ by showing that,  given any $\rm\:f(x)\:$ with more roots than its degree,$\:$ we can quickly compute a nontrivial factor of $\rm\:m\:$ via a $\rm\:gcd$. The quadratic case of this result is at the heart of many integer factorization algorithms, which try to factor $\rm\:m\:$ by searching for a nontrivial square root in $\rm\: \mathbb Z/m,\:$ e.g. a square root of $1$ that is not $\:\pm 1$.