# Is "$x^2=1\implies x=\pm 1$" true on any field? why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

The only elements $x\in\Bbb F_p$ with $x^2=1$ are $\pm1$, right?
Is that true for any field? How do I see that it's true?

Comment: This has been handled many times. Hint: Apply the lack of zero divisors to $$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)=0.$$

Comment: @Surb: In $\mathbb F_2$, $-1=1$. So the statement is still true, it's just that $\pm 1$ is just one element, rather than two.

Comment: It seems rather strange that you asked about "any field" but you accepted an answer that is very far from shedding light on the matter in "any field". When you do things like that you may end up discouraging folks from answering your future questions.

Comment: True, @BillDubuque, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $G=\langle g \rangle$ is a finite cyclic group with even order, $|G|=2n$.
 Then we may list the elements of the group in the following way:
$$ G=\left\{1,g,g^2,\ldots, g^{2n-1}\right\} $$
and see how the map $\varphi:x\mapsto x^2$ acts on $G$: it is a $2$-to-$1$ map, mapping $G$ into the subgroup of squares, also known as the set of quadratic residues:
$$ \varphi(G) = \left\{1,g^2,g^4,\ldots,g^{2n-2}\right\} $$
If now we take some $h\in G$, only two things may happen: $h=g^{2m+1}$, so $h$ is not a quadratic residue, or $h=g^{2m}$, and in such a case $h=(g^m)^2 = (g^{m+n})^2$, i.e. $h$ has two distinct square roots.

If $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ is a finite field, $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}^*$ is a cyclic group with $p^k-1$ elements. Assuming $p\neq 2$, the above considerations apply: $1$ is for sure a quadratic residue, since $1=1^2$, with two distinct square roots, that cannot be anything else than $\pm 1$.

Comment: Explain your downvote.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the reason might be that using group theory to derive this result only for finite fields looks like a big overkill. It's an interesting connection, though. +1

Comment: @lisyarus: someone may agree with you, but I may add that my proof also prove the statement in $\mathbb{Z}/(p^k\mathbb{Z})^*$, that is not a field.

Comment: Well, the usual polynomial-division-based argument works in all integral domains, a much more diverse class.

Comment: @lisyarus: then integral domains *and* cyclic groups with even order look like a nice combo :)

Comment: @lisyarus In fact it is a *characteristic* property of domains, i.e. a commutative ring $R\,$ is a domain iff every nonzero polynomial over $R\,$ has no more roots than its degree.

Comment: @BillDubuque Whoa. That's cool, thanks you! How is it proved?

Comment: @lisyarus The nontrivial direction is sketched in my answer. For the trivial direction in a nondomain there are $\,a,b\neq 0\,$ with $\,ab = 0\,$ so $\,ax=0\,$ has two roots $\,b,0.\,$

Comment: @lisyarus I should add that it is actually useful in the nondomain case too since it can help with factorization. I added a remark about that in  the final paragraph in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, in any ring $1^2=1$ and $(-1)^2=1$.

Next, in any integral domain a polynomial of degree $N$ can have *at most* $N$ roots (a consequence of [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) and nonexistence of zero divisors). So, a polynomial $x^2-1$ can have *at most* two roots.

If the characteristic is not $2$, we have $-1 \neq 1$, so these are *the* two roots. If the characteristic is $2$, we note that now $x^2 - 1 = x^2+1 = x^2 - 2x + 1 = (x-1)^2$, so $1$ is a root of multiplicity $2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ (x\!-\!1)(x\!+\!1) = 0\,\Rightarrow\, x\!-\!1 = 0\,$ or $\,x\!+\!1 = 0\,$ by the field (or domain) axiom that $\, ab = 0\,\Rightarrow\, a=0\,$ or $\,b = 0,\,$ i.e. no zero-divisors exist, i.e. nonzero elts are cancellable (regular).

More generally, by iterating the [Factor Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) we can show that a nonzero polynomial $\,f\,$ over a field (or domain) $D$ has no more roots than its degree $\,n.\,$  Indeed if $\,f\,$ has  $\,\ge n\,$ distinct roots $\,r_i$ then inductively applying the  Factor Theorem (as in the Theorem below) shows $\,f = c(x\!-\!r_1)\cdots (x\!-\!r_n),\,$ so $\, r\ne r_i\,\Rightarrow\, f(r)= c(r\!-\!r_1)\cdots (r\!-\!r_n) \ne 0\,$ by all factors $\ne 0,\,$ and $D$ a domain. Thus $\,f\,$ has at most $\,n\,$ roots. Below we show how the inductive step works.

**Bifactor Theorem** $\ $ Let $\rm\,a,b\in R,\,$ a commutative ring, and $\rm\:f\in R[x]\:$ a polynomial over $\,\rm R.\,$
If $\rm\ \color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b}\ $ is $\,\color{#c00}{\rm cancelable}\,$ in $\rm\,R\,$ (i.e. not a zero-divsor) $ $ then

$$\rm f(a) = 0 = f(b)\ \iff\ f\, =\, (x\!-\!a)(x\!-\!b)\ h\ \ for\ \ some\ \ h\in R[x]$$

**Proof** $\,\ (\Leftarrow)\,$ clear. $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ Applying  [Factor Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) twice, while canceling $\rm\: \color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b},$

$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm\:f(b)= 0 &\ \Rightarrow\ &\rm f(x)\, =\, (x\!-\!b)\,g(x)\ \ for\ \ some\ \ g\in R[x]\\
\rm f(a) = (\color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b})\,g(a) = 0 &\color{#c00}\Rightarrow&\rm g(a)\, =\, 0\,\ \Rightarrow\,\ g(x) \,=\, (x\!-\!a)\,h(x)\ \ for\ \ some\ \ h\in R[x]\\
&\Rightarrow&\rm f(x)\, =\, (x\!-\!b)\,g(x) \,=\, (x\!-\!b)(x\!-\!a)\,h(x)\end{eqnarray}$$

**Remark** $\ $ The theorem  may fail when $\rm\ a\!-\!b\ $ is not cancelable (i.e. is a zero-divisor), e.g.

$$\rm mod\ 8\!:\,\ f(x)=x^2\!-1\,\Rightarrow\,f(3)\equiv 0\equiv f(1)\ \ but\ \  x^2\!-1\not\equiv (x\!-\!3)(x\!-\!1)\equiv x^2\!-4x+3\quad$$

It will prove instructive to examine the above proof in this special case to see how it fails.

As interesting application of this is that we can quickly find a factor of factor $\rm m>1\,$ by a gcd calculation if we are given a polynomial with more roots mod $\rm\, m\,$ than its degree, e.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) where I show how it works for low degree polynomials. This idea underlies some factorization algorithms.