# Find $a$ in $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod b$ given $b$ where $a < b-1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given the equivalence $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod b$ (where $b$ is known) is there an efficient way to determine if an answer other than $a = 1$ exists? Is there an efficient way to find the answer(s), especially the greatest possible value of $a$? The only constraint is $1 < a < b - 1$.

Comment: $b-1$ is another solution, and there's no other solution if $b$ is prime.  Other than that, using the *Chinese remainder theorem* ,  it comes down to the case when $b is prime power.

Comment: So $a \equiv_b -1$ is no good?

Comment: An answer with $1<a<b-1$ exists if and only if $b$ is a power of $2$ or has more than one prime factor; use the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @Servaes:  a power of $2$ *greater than $2^2$*

Comment: @Servaes How would you apply the Chinese remainder theorem here? Sorry, I'm relatively inexperienced in this field

Comment: for example, $x^2\equiv1\bmod15\iff x^2\equiv1\bmod3\land x^2\equiv1\bmod5\iff x\equiv\pm1\bmod3\land x\equiv\pm1\bmod5$

Comment: Factor the modulus then apply CRT as in the linked dupe. There is nothing much faster than that because finding such nontrivial square roots [is equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) to splitting the modulus into nontrivial factors. If $\,a>1$ is the least nontrivial square root then $\,b-a\equiv -a\,$ is the greatest root $\bmod b,\,$ since the roots are closed under negation.