# Show that $29^{41}+41^{29}$ is divisible by 35

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How con I Show that $29^{41}+41^{29}$ is divisible by 35.
**attempt:** I think it shouldn’t be difficult but not sure how to prove it.

29 is not a multiple of 5 nor of 7 same for 41.

Comment: Hint:  what are $29,41\pmod {35}$?

Comment: What have you tried - you've tagged it modular arithmetic ...

Comment: $29^{41}+41^{29} \equiv -1+1\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ ; $29^{41}+41^{29} \equiv 1 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$ therefore $29^{41}+41^{29} \equiv 0 \pmod{35}$

Comment: *Hint*:  Use the *Chinese Remainder theorem* and *Euler-Fermat*'s theorem.

Comment: Hint: $\,J,K$ odd $\Rightarrow (-6)^{J}+ 6^{K}\equiv 0\pmod{5\ \&\ 7}\ $ so also $\bmod 5\cdot 7\ \ $

Comment: Hint: $\,J,K,$ odd $\Rightarrow (-a)^{J}+ a^{K}\equiv 0\pmod{a\!-\!1\ \&\ a\!+\!1}\ $ so also $\bmod a^2-1$ when $\,2\mid a,\,$ since then ${\rm lcm}(a\!-\!1,a\!+\!1) = (a\!-\!1)(a\!+\!1)\,$ by $\gcd(a\!-\!1,a\!+\!1) = \gcd(a\!-\!1,2) = 1\ \ $

Comment: Trivial congruence arithmetic using [congruence laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) shows $\,x\equiv 0\,$ both mod $5$ & $7$ therefore $\,x\equiv 0\,$ mod their lcm $= 5\cdot 7\,$ by CCRT in the linked dupe.

Comment: Alternatively use $\,6^2\equiv 1\pmod{35}\,$ and mod order reduction (cf. 2nd dupe). Such nontrivial sqrts of $1$ [always correspond](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) to factorizations of the modulus into coprime factors.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$29\equiv -6(\mod 35)$$
$$41\equiv 6(\mod 35)$$
and
$$6^2\equiv 1(\mod 35)$$

Answer (score 0):

The diract way:

$29^{41} + 41^{29}$ mod $35$ = $(-6)^{41} + 6^{29}$ mod $35$ = $-6 \cdot (-6)^{40} + 6\cdot6^{28}$ mod $35$ = $-6 \cdot 36 ^{20} + 6 \cdot 36^{14}$ mod $35$ = $- 6 + 6$ mod $35$ = $0$ mod $35$

So we can see that $35$ divides $29^{41} + 41^{29}$.

Comment: direct*  additive inverses raised to odd powers being multiplicative inverses doesn't quite help here sadly ...