# Given $245^2\equiv 1\pmod{2501}$. Find $x,y$ such that $x\cdot y=2501$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given $245^2\equiv 1\pmod{2501}$

Find $x,y$ such that $x\cdot y=2501$. (obviously not $x=1,y=2501$)

How am I suppose to approach this problem ? I don't know how to start, can't see how the given helps me to find $x,y$.

Help please, thanks !

Comment: $a^2-1 = (a+1)(a-1)$.

Comment: Please see the edit to learn how to write modular equations in MathJax.

Comment: See the $\,\rm \deg f = 2\,$ case in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) in the linked dupe, and see its many "Linked" questions for more examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the factorization of $a^2-1$ is $(a-1)(a+1)$. So,
\begin{align*}245^2-1^2 &\equiv 0 \mod 2501 \\
(245-1)(245+1) & \equiv 0 \mod 2501 \\ 
244\cdot 246 &\equiv 0 \mod 2501.\end{align*}
Note that $244\cdot 246 = 2501 \cdot 24 \implies \frac{244}{4} \cdot \frac{246}{6} = 2501 \implies \boxed{61 \cdot 41} = 2501.$

Comment: thanks , how you get $244\cdot 246 = 2501 \cdot 24$ ? (without a calculator)

Comment: You could just multiply it out and divide because there seems to be no other way(a prime factorization could help but that could be used to directly solve this problem without using the modulus).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).